# Showing that the elements $6$ and $2+2\sqrt{5}$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ have no gcd

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In showing that the elements $6$ and $2+2\sqrt{5}$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ have no gcd, I was thinking of trying the following method.

If the ideal $(6)$ + $(2+2\sqrt{5})$ is not principal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ then there does not exist $d \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ such that $(6)$ + $(2+2\sqrt{5}) = (d)$ and therefore there is no gcd.

However this uses the lemma that if $\gcd(x,y) = d$ then $(x) + (y) = (d)$, is this true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true in general that if $\gcd(x,y)=d$ then $(x)+(y)=(d)$.  In particular, if $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (the ring of polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$ in the indeterminate $x$), then $\gcd(2,x)=1$ (since any divisor of $2$ in $R$ must be an integer, and the only integers that divide $x$ in $R$ are $\pm 1$), however $(2,x)=(2)+(x)\subsetneq R$.

More generally, integral domains for which gcds can be written as a linear combination are known as [Bézout domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout_domain)--domains where every finitely generated ideal is principal.

As Bill mentions in his answer, GCD domains (ie integral domains in which every pair of nonzero elements has a gcd) satisfy the property that every [irreducible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element) is [prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element).  In particular, if $R$ is an integral domain in which every nonzero nonunit can factor into irreducibles, then $R$ is a GCD domain if and only if $R$ is a [UFD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain).

As for showing that $6$ and $2+2\sqrt{-5}$ have no gcd, this can also be done easily enough using the norm function $N:\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]\rightarrow\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ defined by $N(a+b\sqrt{-5})=a^2+5b^2$.  In particular for all $\alpha,\beta\in R$, $N(\alpha\beta)=N(\alpha)N(\beta)$, $N(\alpha)=0$ if and only if $\alpha=0$, and $N(\alpha)=1$ if and only if $\alpha\in U(R)$ (proving this is a canonical abstract algebra exercise).  So, if there is a gcd of 6 and $2+2\sqrt{-5}$, then there must be a common divisor of 3 and $1+\sqrt{-5}$ (since 2 divides both 6 and $2+2\sqrt{-5}$ in $R$).

Thus, there exists $\alpha\in R$ such that $\alpha \mid 3$ and $\alpha \mid 1+\sqrt{-5}$. Taking the norm (and using the norm properties above), we have $N(\alpha)\mid 9$ and $N(\alpha) \mid 6$.  Therefore, it follows that either $N(\alpha)=1$ or $N(\alpha)=3$. However, the fact that there are no integer solutions to the equation $a^2+5b^2=3$ (why?) implies that there is no element in $R$ having a norm of 3. Therefore $N(\alpha)=1$ and $\gcd(3,1+\sqrt{-5})=1$.

Now suppose that $6$ and $2+2\sqrt{-5}$ have a gcd. Then we have $2=2\gcd(3,1+\sqrt{-5})=\gcd(6,2+2\sqrt{-5})$.  However, we reach a contradiction as $1+\sqrt{-5}$ is a common divisor of both 6 and $2+2\sqrt{-5}$, but $1+\sqrt{-5}$ does not divide 2 (Hint: suppose it does and use the norm).  Therefore $\gcd(6,2+2\sqrt{-5})$ does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to deduce that gcds do not exist is due to failure of Euclid's Lemma. Let's recall it.

**Lemma** $\rm\ \ (a,b)\ =\ (ac,bc)/c\quad$  if $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ exists.

**Proof** $\rm\quad d\ |\ a,b\ \iff\ dc\ |\ ac,bc\ \iff\ dc\ |\ (ac,bc)\ \iff\ d\:|\:(ac,bc)/c\ \ $ **QED**

Generally $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ need not exist, as is most insightfully viewed as failure of

**Euclid's Lemma**  $\rm\quad a\ |\ bc\ $ and $\rm\ (a,b)=1\ \Rightarrow\ a\ |\ c\quad$ if $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ exists.

**Proof** $\ \ $ If $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ exists then $\rm\ a\ |\ ac,bc\ \Rightarrow\ a\ |\ (ac,bc) = (a,b)\:c = c\ $  by Lemma. $\ \ $ **QED**

Hence if $\rm\: a,b,c\: $ fail to satisfy the Euclid Lemma $\Rightarrow\:$,
namely  if  $\rm\ a\ |\ bc\ $  and  $\rm\ (a,b) = 1\ $  but $\rm\ a\nmid c\:$, then one immediately deduces that the gcd $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ fails to exist. For the special case $\rm\:a\:$ is an atom (i.e. irreducible), the implication reduces to: atom $\Rightarrow$ prime. So it suffices to find a nonprime atom
in order to exhibit a pair of elements whose gcd fails to exist. This task is a bit simpler, e.g. for $\rm\ \omega = 1 + \sqrt{-5}\ \in\ \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]\ $ we have atom $\rm\: 2\ |\ \omega'\:\! \omega = 6\:,\:$ but $\rm\ 2\nmid \omega',\:\!\omega,\:$ so $\rm\:2\:$ is not prime. Therefore we deduce that the gcd $\rm\: (2\:\!\omega,\:\! \omega'\omega)\ =\ (2+2\sqrt{-5},\:6)\ $ fails to exist in $\rm\ \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]\:$.

Note that if the gcd $\rm\: (ac,bc)\ $ fails to exist then this implies that the ideal $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ is not principal. Therefore we've *constructively*  deduced that the failure of Euclid's lemma immediately yields both a nonexistent gcd and a nonprincipal ideal.

That the $\Rightarrow$ in Euclid's lemma implies that Atoms are Prime $\rm(:= AP)$ is denoted $\rm\ D\ \Rightarrow AP\ $ in the list of domains closely related to GCD domains in my [post here.](http://groups.google.com/groups?selm=y8z8yto8k85.fsf@nestle.ai.mit.edu) There you will find links to further literature on domains closely related to GCD domains. See especially the referenced comprehensive survey by D.D. Anderson: *GCD domains, Gauss' lemma, and contents of polynomials*, 2000.

See also my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/if-a-m-and-a-1-m-prove-aa-1-m/3149#3149) for the general *universal* definitions of $\rm GCD,\: LCM$ and for further remarks on how such $\iff$ definitions enable slick proofs, and [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/upper-and-lower-bounds-of-emptyset/3832#3832) for another simple example of such.