# How to determine if this is a principal ideal domain?

Tags: ring-theory

Consider $\mathbb{Z[\sqrt{-5}]}=a+b\sqrt{-5}$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. My understanding is that an integral domain is a PID if every ideal in the ring is principal.

For the above example, this I can see that it is an integral domain because it's a subring of $\mathbb{C}$, which contains 1. My issue comes with showing the 'principal' part, where I'm not quite sure where to start.

Comment: No, it's not a subring of $\mathbb{Z}$. And it's not a PID, because it's not factorial. Is there a non invertible common divisor of $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$?

Comment: What does containing $1$ have to do with being an integral domain? It is true that it is an integral domain, but $1\in \mathbb C$ is not the reason for that.

Answer (score 3):

In $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}],$ $2$ and $3$ are irreducible, since $6 = 2 \cdot 3$ and $6 = (1 + \sqrt{-5})(1 - \sqrt{-5}).$ Observe that $U(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]) = \{\pm1\}$ (group of units). Therefore, the factorization of $6$ are truly different $\Longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not a unique factorization domain. Since all principal ideal domains are unique factorization domains, it follows that $\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{-5} \right]$ is not a principal ideal domain either.

Comment: In particular, the set $\{a+b\sqrt{-5}\mid a\equiv b\pmod 2\}$  is an ideal which is not principle.

Answer (score 1):

**Euclid's Lemma** [(2-line proof)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/148247/242)   $\ \ \gcd(a,b)=1,\ a\ |\ bc\  \Rightarrow\ a\mid c\ \ $ **if** $\ \gcd(ac,bc)\ $ exists.

If this fails, i.e. if  $\,\gcd(a,b) = 1,\ a\mid bc\ $  but $\ a\nmid c\:$, then the $\,\gcd(ac,bc)\ $ fails to exist, so the ideal $\,(ac,bc)\,$ is not principal. Apply to: $ $ irreducible $\, 2\mid \omega\bar\omega = 6,\,$ but $\, 2\nmid \omega,\bar\omega,\,\ \omega = 1\!+\!\sqrt{-5}$.