# Show that $n,1+\sqrt{11}\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{11}]$ generate the whole ring if $n$ ends in $7$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I am starting to learn about rings and ideals in abstract algebra. I came across a textbook problem that I am having a lot of trouble solving:

> Prove that for any positive integer $n$ ending in $7$, the ideal generated by $n$ and $1+\sqrt{11}$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{11}]$ is trivial. In other words, that it is the same as the whole ring.

I would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: I have gone through the ring $Z$ and I think I have a good understanding of it and its ideals. I just saw this question, and I was very curious. I do not know yet about Norm-Euclidean rings. Also related to the question above, how do you represent elements in the ideal $\mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{11}$? Are they of the form $(n, 1+\sqrt{11}) = \{nx + y ( 1+ \sqrt{11}) | x, y \; \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{11}] \}$?

Comment: Norm Euclidean implies that we have a gcd. This is used in the answers. See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148225/showing-that-the-elements-6-and-22-sqrt5-in-mathbbz-sqrt5-have-n), where there is no gcd of tow elements.

Comment: Is it possible to prove this without using the $gcd$ argument?

Answer (score 2):

Ideals are *closed under norm:* $\,w\in I\Rightarrow N(w) = w\bar w \in I.\,$ Here $\,w = 1+\sqrt{11}\,$ has norm ${-}10$ so $\,I\supset (10,n) = (10,\,n\bmod 7) = (10,7) = 1,\,$ so $\,I = (1).\,$ Similarly every ideal contains the gcd of the norms of all generators (a special case of the [method of simpler multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242)), e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3895817/242).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that the ideal also contains the element
$$(1+\sqrt{11})(1-\sqrt{11})=1-11^2=-10.$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $n$ is positive. Then we have that $n=10k+7$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $(1-\sqrt{11})(1+\sqrt{11})=-10$.
Thus it follows that $\gcd(n, 10)=1$, thus $1 \in I$.

Comment: $n=10k+7$ thus $3n=3 \times 10k +2 \times 10 +1$, so $(3k+2)10+1=3n$. Finally the result is that $3n+(3k+2)(-10)=1$. Sorry I was not explicit. :)