# An ideal in $\Bbb Z[i]$ is $(1)$ if its generators have coprime norms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, gaussian-integers

Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be three elements of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, the ring of Gaussian integers. We define the following to be  subset of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$:

$$(a,b,c)=\{ax+by+cz:\ x,y,z \in\mathbb{Z}[i]\}.$$

We know that $(a,b,c)$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Show that the ideal $(-1+3i, -1+5i,-4+7i$) is equal to $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ .

**What I have done so far:**

I have factorised the three elements into a product of irreducible elments in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$:

$(-1+3i)=(1+i)(1+2i)$, $(-1+5i)=(1+i)(2+3i)$,$(-4+7i)=(2+3i)(1+2i)$

However I don't know how to show that the ideal is equal to  $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. I think it might have something to do with the norms of the three elements in the ideal...

Comment: To show that the ideal $(a, b, c)$ is equal to $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ you just need to show that $1\in (a,b,c)$. This is true in general by the way. Any ideal $I\subset R$ is equal to the ring $R$ if it contains the multiplicative identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very many ways of handling a specific question like this. Let me show you the technique I most often use, which has nothing to do with the fact that $\Bbb Z[i]$ has unique factorization.
\begin{align}
(−1+3,−1+5,−4+7)&=(-1+3i,2i,-4+7i)\\
&=(-1+3i,2,7i)\\
&=(-1+3i,2,7)=(-1+3i,1)=(1)\,.
\end{align}
If it’s not self-explanatory, I can elaborate.

**EDIT**: Elaboration.
Let’s call the three Gaussian numbers $U, V, W$, in the order you gave.
Step 1 (first line) replaces $(U,V,W)$ by $(U,V-U,W)$. Do you see why the two triples generate the same ideal? (If you don’t see this immediately, show that every number of form $aU+bV+cW$ is also of the form $a'U+b'(V-U)+c'W$, and also show the converse. This  understanding is the most important part of the deal. Make sure you absorb it.)

Second step combines two steps, replacing the generator $2i$ by a number that is $2i$ times the unit $-i$. Do you see why this ideal is the same as the preceding? Once you’ve done that, do the same thing as in step 1, by keeping the second generator but adding twice it to the third generator. Do you see why $(-1+3i,2,-4+7i)$ is the same ideal as $(-1+3i,2,7i)$?

Next step replaces $7i$ by $7$, same as the first part of step 2.

Final step uses the fact that if $2$ and $7$ are in the ideal, so is $1$, which is enough to make the ideal the whole ring.

I hope it’s clear now.

Comment: @Rox It's essentially the Euclidean algorithm. Generally applying [an invertible ("unimodular") linear transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3533044/242) to the ideal generators ("basis") preserves the ideal, so we aim to do this in a way that "simplifies" the generators, e.g. reduces their norm (cf. [norm Euclidean number rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Norm-Euclidean_fields)). But here it suffices to work only with the norms since they are already coprime - see my answer.

Comment: Everything you say is true, @BillDubuque , but that’s not the way I look at things. I just plow through it, looking to simplify the set of generators down to something transparent.

Comment: @Rox I added an alternative proof to my answer explaining an equivalent *equational* view of the ideal arithmetic methods used above (which you will likely find more intuitive; exercise: do Lubin's exact computation this way).

Comment: @Lubin Btw, do you know if there is any "standard" name [for this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3387196/242)

Comment: Sorry, @BillDubuque , I’m notoriously ignorant of standard terminologies.

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed out in the comments: In general, if $R$ is a commutative ring with identity and $I\subset R$ is an ideal, then $I=R$ if and only if $1\in I$.

So it suffices to show that there exist $a,b,c\in\Bbb{Z}[i]$ such that
$$a(-1+3i)+b(-1+5i)+c(-4+7i)=1.$$

Comment: Why are you in doubt?

Comment: @Rox Integers are of the form $x + yi$ but with $y = 0$.

Comment: @Rox yes the proof is complete.

Comment: Trial and error is fine

Answer (score 0):

**Easy way:** $ $  ideal $I\,$ contains the norms $\,w\bar w\,$ of every generator $\,w\,$ so by Bezout it also contains the gcd of the norms = $(10,2\color{#c00}6,5\color{#0a0}5)=(10,\color{#c00}6,\color{#0a0}5)=(10,1,5)\!=\!1\,$ by Euclid. So $\,1\!\in\! I\Rightarrow I\! =\! \Bbb Z[i]$.

**Remark** $ $ As explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3882525/242) this can be viewed  an instance of the [method of simpler multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242) (or, equivalently, the correspondence or Third Isomorphism Theorem,  from a *structural* viewpoint). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3983720/242) for an analogous example using the norm *and* trace.

Because the norm map is *multiplicative* it preserves many properties related to factorization. For example, in many favorable contexts (e.g. Galois) a number ring enjoys unique factorization iff its monoid of norms does. For further interesting examples see the papers of Bumby, Dade, Lettl, Coykendall cited in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95015/242).

---

**Alternatively** working $\!\bmod I\,$ (or, equivalently, in $\,\Bbb Z[i]/I)\,$ simplifies *ideal* arithmetic (as in Lubin's answer) to more intuitive arithmetic of *numbers* (ring elements), e.g. here we find by subtracting neighboring stacked congruences that

$$\begin{align} \color{#c00}{3i\equiv 1}\\ 5i\equiv 1\\ 7i\equiv 4\end{align}\Rightarrow 
\begin{array}{} 2i\equiv \color{#0a0}0\\ 2i\equiv \color{#0a0}3\end{array}\Rightarrow\, 
 \color{#0a0}{0\equiv 3}\,\Rightarrow\, 0\equiv \color{#c00}{3i\equiv 1}\qquad$$

While it may seem ad hoc at first glance, as long as we eventually keep finding smaller (norm) elements this will eventually yield the gcd, due to the fact that $\,\Bbb Z[i]\:\!$ is (norm) Euclidean. Thus, instead of *mechanically* applying the Euclidean algorithm, we can often use our intuition to step outside the algorithm to optimize it (one way is as above - using "simpler multiples", where "simpler" need not always imply smaller norm).