# Quadratic integer $\alpha$ is coprime to its conjugate if its norm and trace are coprime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

in a certain proof I'm working with the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$ where $d=n^g-1$ is squarefree, $n>1$ is odd and $g>1$.

Then, as $d \equiv 2 \hspace{1mm} (\operatorname{mod} 4)$ I know that this ring is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$, and in this ring I have the following factorization of the ideal generated by $n$
$$(n)^g=(n^g)=(d+1)=(1+\sqrt{-d})(1-\sqrt{-d})$$
Know, I need to show that this two ideal factors are coprime and the text I'm using states that this fact derives from $n$ being odd but I don't see why.

I know that if a prime ideal $P$ divides both $(1+\sqrt{-d})$ and $(1-\sqrt{-d})$ then it divides $(n)$ and as the norm of $P$ is a power of a prime and the norm of $(n)$ is $n^2$ there is an odd prime dividing the norms of the two factors, which are both $1+d=n^g$, but I don't see any contradiction following this reasoning.

Any ideas?

Comment: The gcd of two elements divides their sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\ (a,b)\supset (ab,a\!+\!b).\,$ You have $\,ab\,$ odd, $\,a+b\,$ even so $\ldots$

When $\,b = \bar a\,$ it says: $ $ if $\,a\,$ has coprime norm and trace then $\,a,\bar a\,$ are coprime.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3895817/242) for further intuition (method of *simpler multiples*) and generalizations (Bumby).

Comment: I don't get the clue, when you say that $ab$ is odd and $a+b$ is even, do you mean their norms? And in that case, how do you know that the norm of $a+b$ is even?

Comment: @Eparoh Your trace is $\,a + b = 1\!+\!\sqrt{-d} + 1\!-\!\sqrt{-d} \,=\, 2\ \ $

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand what do you mean.

Comment: For the converse (in general), see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/257434/242) and its links.