# Prove Or Disprove That $(2i-1,2i+3) \subset \mathbb{Z}[i]$ Is a Prime Ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

As the title states, I'm trying to either prove or disprove that $(2i-1,2i+3) \subset \mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a prime ideal.

I know that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a Euclidean domain and thus a PID and hence a UFD, and that there's an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[i] \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/ \langle x^2+1 \rangle$, so I believe it suffices to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/ \langle x^2+1,2x-1,2x+3 \rangle$ or $\mathbb{Z}[i] / \langle 2i-1,2i+3 \rangle$ is atleast an integral domain, but I'm not sure how, since in both cases I found the algebra extremely tedious to try and verify these claims (unless I'm missing something).

Thank you.

Comment: Find a single generator of the ideal and check if it is irreducible/prime. Note that the ideal contains $4$, so the generator must be a divisor of $4$. There aren't that many...

Comment: Same methods in the linked dupe work here, e.g. as  in [this answer,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3895817/242) the ideal contains the generator norms $5,13$ so it contains $(5,13) = 1\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ (-2i)(2i-1) + (-1)(2i+3) = 1 $$

The ideal $(2i-1,2i+3)$ is the entire ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, so it is by definition not a prime ideal.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).