# Does Euclid lemma hold for GCD domains?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Exercise $ 10 $ of Section $ 3 $ of Chapter III of Hungerford’s *Algebra* states that if $ R $ is a UFD and if $ a,b $ are relatively prime, then $ a | bc $ implies $ a | c $, something that is easy to prove using the uniqueness of factorization into irreducibles. So I want to ask whether this holds if $ R $ is just an integral domain (in order for divisibility to make sense) such that $ \gcd(a,b) $ exists for all $ a,b \in R $.

I can prove this property if I could show that $\gcd(x,y)\gcd(x,z)=\gcd(x,zy)$ or showing that $\gcd(x,y)=1=\gcd(x,z)$ implies $\gcd(x,zy)=1$, this is the part where I've been stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: "an integral domain such that gcd(a,b) exists for all a,b" what does that mean? If it means anything close to what I think it does, then $R$ is a PID and hence a UFD and so you're done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Euclid's Lemma is true in gcd domains (domains where any two nonzero elements have a gcd), but the lemma may fail in domains where some gcds fail to exist (e.g. below). Below is some general discussion on this and related matters in an arbitrary integral domain.

**Lemma** $\rm\ \ (a,b)\ =\ (ac,bc)/c\quad$  if $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ exists $\rm\quad$ (GCD distributive law )

**Proof** $\rm\quad d\ |\ a,b\ \iff\ dc\ |\ ac,bc\ \iff\ dc\ |\ (ac,bc)\ \iff\ d|(ac,bc)/c$

But generally $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ need not exist, as is most insightfully viewed as failure of

**Euclid's Lemma**  $\rm\quad a\ |\ bc\ $ and $\rm\ (a,b)=1\ \Rightarrow\ a\ |\ c\quad$ if $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ exists.

**Proof** $\ \ $ If $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ exists then $\rm\ a\ |\ ac,bc\ \Rightarrow\ a\ |\ (ac,bc) = (a,b)\:c = c\ $  by the Lemma.

Therefore if $\rm\: a,b,c\: $ fail to satisfy the Euclid Lemma $\Rightarrow\:$,
namely  if  $\rm\ a\ |\ bc\ $  and  $\rm\ (a,b) = 1\ $  but $\rm\ a\nmid c\:$, then one immediately deduces that the gcd $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ fails to exist.$\:$  For the special case that $\rm\:a\:$ is an atom (i.e. irreducible), the implication reduces to: atom $\Rightarrow$ prime. So it suffices to find a nonprime atom
in order to exhibit a pair of elements whose gcd fails to exist. This task is a bit simpler, e.g. for $\rm\ \omega = 1 + \sqrt{-3}\ \in\ \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]\ $ we have that the atom $\rm\: 2\ |\ \omega'\: \omega = 4\:,\:$ but $\rm\ 2\nmid \omega',\:\omega\:,\:$ so $\rm\:2\:$ is not prime. Therefore the gcd $\rm\: (2\:\omega,\ \omega'\:\omega)\ =\ (2+2\sqrt{-3},\:4)\ $ fails to exist in $\rm\ \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]\:$.

Note that if the gcd $\rm\: (ac,bc)\ $ fails to exist then this implies that the ideal $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ is not principal. Therefore we've *constructively*  deduced that the failure of Euclid's lemma immediately yields both a nonexistent gcd and a nonprincipal ideal.

That the $\Rightarrow$ in Euclid's lemma implies that Atoms are Prime $\rm(:= AP)$ is denoted $\rm\ D\ \Rightarrow AP\ $ in the list of domains closely related to GCD domains in  [this post.](http://groups.google.com/groups?selm=y8z8yto8k85.fsf@nestle.ai.mit.edu) There you will find links to further literature on domains closely related to GCD domains. See especially the referenced comprehensive survey by D.D. Anderson: *GCD domains, Gauss' lemma, and contents of polynomials*, 2000.

See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/if-a-m-and-a-1-m-prove-aa-1-m/3149#3149) for the general *universal* definitions of $\rm GCD,\: LCM$ and for further remarks on how such $\iff$ definitions enable slick proofs, and [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/upper-and-lower-bounds-of-emptyset/3832#3832) for another simple example of such.

Comment: In a gcd domain, nevertheless integral domain, $/c$ is not defined, how too write $(a,b)=(ac,bc)/c$?

Answer (score 7):

This holds true if *all* pairs of elements have a $\gcd$, in other words in a gcd-domain.
However it fails if just $\gcd(a,b)$ is required to be defined.

To see the latter point, consider your favourite non-UFD, like $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ where $(1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})=6=2\times3$ are two distinct factorizations into irreducibles. Now with $a=2$, $b=1+\sqrt{-5}$ and $c=1-\sqrt{-5}$, one has $2=a\mid bc=6$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$, but $a\not\mid c$.

That existence of all $\gcd$s implies that the implication *is* valid is explained in the other answers: supposing that $a\mid bc$, then since also $a\mid ac$ it follows that $a\mid\gcd(bc,ac)=\gcd(a,b)c=c$. Here the equality $\gcd(bc,ac)=\gcd(a,b)c$ (in the quotient set $R/{\sim}$, where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation of multiplication by invertible elements, because it is only there that $\gcd$ expression have a well-defined meaning) holds because on one hand $\gcd(a,b)c$ is a common divisor of $bc$ and $ac$, and on the other hand $\gcd(bc,ac)$, which is assumed to exist, divides $\gcd(a,b)c$: it is a multiple $xc$ of the common divisor $c$ of $ac$ and $bc$, and now $x$ must divide both $a$ and $b$ (since $xc$ divides $ac$ and $bc$) and therefore $x\mid\gcd(a,b)$.

By the way existence of all $\gcd$s does not imply that $R$ us a UFD, since it does not imply that factorisations into irreducibles exist in the first place.

*Added.* It may also be interesting to note if we replace the hypothesis $\gcd(a,b)=1$ for "$a,b$ are relatively prime" by the condition that $ab$ is a  least common multiple of $a$ and $b$, then we get this instance of Euclid's lemma without having to require the existence of other $\def\lcm{\operatorname{lcm}}\lcm$s or $\gcd$s: from $a\mid bc$ and the obvious $b\mid bc$ follow $ab=\lcm(a,b)\mid bc$, and then by simplification by $b$ one gets $a\mid c$.

Answer (score 4):

> Let $R$ be a GCD domain and $x,y,z\in R$. Then $(xy,xz)=x(y,z)$.

Set $d=(y,z)$. Then $y=dy'$ and $z=dz'$ with $(y',z')=1$. Let $\delta=(xy,xz)$. Obviously $dx\mid\delta$, so $\delta=dxw$. Since $xy=\delta u$, $xz=\delta v$, it follows $dxy'=dxuw$ and therefore $y'=uw$. Similarly one gets $x'=vw$. Now it follows that $w=1$.

> Let $R$ be a GCD domain and $x,y,z\in R$. If $(x,y)=1$ and $(x,z)=1$, then $(x,yz)=1$.

Take $\alpha$ a common divisor of $x$ and $yz$. Obviously $\alpha$ is a common divisor of $xz$ and $yz$, so $\alpha|(xz,yz)$, or $\alpha\mid z(x,y)$. Because $(x,y)=1$, $\alpha\mid z$. Also $\alpha\mid x$, so $\alpha | (x,z)$, therefore it is $1$ as $(x,z)=1$.

> Let $R$ be a GCD domain. Then $(a,b)=1$ and $a\mid bc$ implies $a\mid c$.

If $d=(a,c)$, then $a=da_1$, $c=dc_1$ and $(a_1,c_1)=1$. Since $a\mid bc$ we have $a_1\mid bc_1$. But $(a_1,b)=1$ and $(a_1,c_1)=1$, and thus $(a_1,bc_1)=1$. This shows that $a_1=1$, so $a\mid c$.