# Annihilators in matrix rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, finite-rings

Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring. For $n>1$ consider the full matrix ring $M_n(R)$. For a matrix $A\in M_n(R)$ is true that the cardinality of the  left annihilator (in $M_n(R)$) of $A$ equals the cardinality of the right annhilator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this isn't true in general, but it's true in principal ideal rings. Consider $R=\mathbb{F}_2[x,y]/(x,y)^2$ (a finite ring that isn't a principal ideal ring, which I found in [this answer by Zev](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75709/6622)). The matrix

$$A=\pmatrix{x&x\\y&y}$$

annihilates the $16$ vectors that have no constant term, both on the left and on the right, but on the right it also annihilates the $16$ vectors that have a constant term in both components, for a total of $32$. Thus the left annihilator in $M_n(R)$ has $256$ elements, whereas the right annihilator has $1024$.

However, if $R$ is an elementary divisor ring, we can bring $A$ into [Smith normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) using invertible matrices. Since this is diagonal, its left and right annihilators are the same up to transposition, and the invertible matrices don't change their cardinality. (See [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44576).)

According to Theorem 15.9 in *Matrices over commutative rings* by William Brown, all principal ideal rings are elementary divisor rings. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) only claims this for principal ideal *domains*.) According to [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1956-082-02/S0002-9947-1956-0078979-8/S0002-9947-1956-0078979-8.pdf), a necessary condition for a ring to be an elementary divisor ring is that all finitely generated ideals are principal.  Since in a finite ring all ideals are finitely generated, a finite elementary divisor ring must be a principal ideal ring. Thus a finite ring is an elementary divisor ring if and only if it is a principal ideal ring.

Comment: This might be weird since I'm asking like five years later, but do you know more references where one can learn about Hermite/elementary divisor rings besides the book "Matrices over commutative rings".

Comment: @Xam This might be weird since I'm replying like five years later, but you may want to have a look at the book Matrices - Theory and Applications, by Denis Serre.