# $\gcd \cdot \mathrm{lcm}$ in a commutative ring with zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, gcd-and-lcm

It looks like the formula $\gcd(a,b) \cdot \mathrm{lcm}(a,b) \sim a \cdot b$ works for any cyclic ring or rng:
[$\gcd \cdot \mathrm{lcm}$ for cyclic rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3138823/427611)

I am looking for an example of a commutative ring or rng where the formula is not working.

Let's redefine *associates* $(\sim)$ as elements that generate the same principal ideal for the task.
This definition is equivalent for commutative rings, but weaker for rngs.

**Update**

Let's define a Prüfer ring/rng as a ring/rng where $(A + B) \cdot (A \cap B) = A \cdot B$
for any ideals $A$ and $B$.

Let's use the example with $\mathbb Z[x]$ from here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/58358/427611

Taking $A = (2)$ and $B = (x)$;
$A \cdot B = (2) \cdot (x)$ contains element $2x$;
$(A + B) \cdot (A \cap B) = ((2) + (x)) \cdot ((2) \cap (x))$ does not contain $2x$;
Therefore, $(A + B) \cdot (A \cap B) \ne A \cdot B$.

Thus, $\mathbb Z[x]$ is not a Prüfer ring,
and the $\rm gcd \cdot lcm$ formula should not work for $A = (2)$ and $B = (x)$.

However,
$\gcd(2, x) = 1$;
$\mathrm{lcm}(2, x) = 2x$;
$\gcd(2, x) \cdot \mathrm{lcm}(2, x) = 2x = 2 \cdot x$.

The $\gcd \cdot \mathrm{lcm}$ formula works for $A = (2)$ and $B = (x)$!
Thus, not being a Prüfer ring is not sufficient to break the $\rm gcd \cdot lcm$ law.
Is this correct?

Comment: Equivalent to which definition?

Comment: @BillDubuque: To the one from the linked question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3138823/427611

Comment: Then your claim is not true, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/863228/242). I recommend that you peruse the papers cited there to familiarize yourself with the complexities of divisor theory in rings with zero divisors.

Comment: @BillDubuque: The claim that $Ra = Rb \iff a|b$ and $b|a$ in a commutative ring is in here (p.717): https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267013690_Associate_elements_in_commutative_rings. Is it not correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I misunderstood what you meant by redefining.

Comment: @BillDubuque Could you check my update, please? I got confused with the Prüfer rings.