# Products of ideals being a subset of their intersection.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and let $I$, $J$ be ideals.
Define $IJ$ to be all elements of $R$ of the form $ a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + . . . + a_nb_n $
where $n ≥ 1$ and $a_1, a_2, . . . , a_n $ are in I and $b_1, b_2, . . . , b_n $ are in J.

Prove that $ IJ \subset I \cap J $

This seems really surprising at first glance until I wrote out a couple of examples and found that ideals of the same ring have a lot of things in common. In fact they had everything in common in the cases I found. I'm not really sure how to formally write out this argument and would like to know: why they are not simply equal?

Comment: You take an element of the left hand side and then you immediately see that it is contained in both $I$ and $J$ by the very basic property of an ideal.

Comment: You might want to look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109833/when-is-a-product-of-two-ideals-strictly-included-in-their-intersection)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$IJ\subseteq IR\subseteq I$

$IJ\subseteq RJ\subseteq J$

Therefore $IJ\subseteq I\cap J$.

An example to show they don't have to be equal:

Consider the ideal generated by $x$ in $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2)$, and use that ideal for both $I$ and $J$.