# $(\alpha, \beta)^n=(\alpha^n, \beta^n)$ in Dedekind domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

It is a sometimes useful lemma that if $\mathfrak{a}=(\alpha, \beta)$ is an ideal of a Dedekind domain $A$, then $\mathfrak{a}^n=(\alpha^n, \beta^n)$. Of course, this is easy to prove, but I'd like to be able to just give a reference. However, having looked in Neukirch's, Marcus' and Lang's books, I was not able to find one - do you know a reference for this fact?

Comment: Is a post here also a reference? I found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250493/xy-in-x2-y2-if-r-is-a-dedekind-domain?noredirect=1&lq=1), which should give what you want.

Comment: Hm, I would obviously have hoped for a textbook or something like that, but I guess it's better than nothing ...

Comment: This is an exercise in Gilmer's _Multiplicative Ideal Theory_, in the section on Prüfer domains

Comment: @Lukas Heger, thank you! Although the edition of the book I found in the library apparently didn't have any exercises, you get the result by combining two of the theorems proved there.