# Does $I(J\cap K)=IJ\cap IK$ hold in a finitely generated polynomial $K$-algebra for $K$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, integral-domain

Let $K$ be a field and $R:=K[X_1,X_2,\dots, X_n]$ for a certain $n\in\mathbb N$. If $I,J,K$ are three ideals of $R$, can we conclude that $I(J\cap K)=IJ\cap IK$?

Comment: no. it doesnt hold in general.

Comment: @Unknown Any counterexample?

Comment: This is one of many equivalent characterizations of Prufer domains, e.g. see $(13)$ in [this long list.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14109/when-does-the-modular-law-apply-to-ideals-in-a-commutative-ring/14122#14122)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> An integral domain $R$ is Prüfer iff for any non-zero ideals $I,J,K$ of $R$ the following holds: $I(J\cap K)=IJ\cap IK$ (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_domain#Definitions).)

A polynomial ring over a field is Prüfer iff $n=1$.

A concrete conterexample: $R=K[X,Y]$, $I=(X,Y)$, $J=(X)$, and $K=(Y)$.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if $R$ is a commutative ring with unity and $A,I,J$ are three ideals, then
$$
A (I \cap J) \subseteq AI \cap AJ
$$
because any element of $A (I \cap J)$ can be simultaneously seen as an element of $AI$ and of $AJ$.

The reverse inclusion holds if $A$ and $X \cap Y$ are coprime because in that case $A$ is coprime with $X$ and $Y$, too, so
$$
A (X \cap Y) = A \cap (X \cap Y) = (A \cap X) \cap (A \cap Y) = AX \cap AY
$$
I don't think that it should hold in general, but right now I can't think of a counterexample.

Comment: I know several counterexamples in some ill-behaved rings. So I just wonder if it holds in polynomial rings.