# A concrete example of an ideal $I\subseteq K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and coprime polynomials $f,g$ such that $(I,f)\cap (I,g)\neq (I,fg)$

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, monomial-ideals

I know that in a polyomial ring $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ over a field $K$, given a monomial ideal $I$ and two coprime monomials $f,g\notin I$, it holds $$(I,f)\cap (I,g)=(I,fg)$$
However, I've been unproductively trying to find an explicit case where the identity fails and one of the three ideals $I, (f), (g)$ is not monomial ($f,g$ still coprime, of course). Can someone provide a classic example, or a link, or a way to find it other than fishing for a lucky guess?

Comment: Do you have a source for this theorem?

Comment: @alphacapture you use modular law ([which holds for triplets of monomial ideals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14109/when-does-the-modular-law-apply-to-ideals-in-a-commutative-ring)) twice.

Comment: What if I take $I = (y)$, $f = x - y$, $g = x + y$? I think it's a nice picture.

Comment: Well, there are those times when you assume everything is complicated! Thank you all.