# A number theory question on Dedekind rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

My friend asks me a question,however I have no idea.

Is the integer ring $O_{\mathbb{C}}$ of complex field $\mathbb{C}$ a Dedekind domain?I am not familiar with it,I search help for my dear friend...If the field is a number field(Finite extension of quotient field $\mathbb{Q}$),then the answer is YES.However $\mathbb{C}$ is not a finite algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Is the ring Noetherian ?

Comment: Do you mean the ring of all algebraic integers?

Comment: Exactly...What's your opinion?

Comment: I don't know whether it's Noetherian...That's difficult for me because it's hard to imagine the structure of rings or all algebraic integers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the ring of all algebraic integers, the answer is no, as it is not even a noetherian domain, as observed in a comment.

However, as the algebraic closure of $\mathbf Q$ in $\mathbf C$ is the direct limit of its finite subextensions, the ring of algebraic integers is the direct limit of Dedekind domains, the rings of integers of these subextensions, and hence it is a *Prüfer domain*. One of the many characterisations of Prüfer domains is that all *finitely generated* ideals are invertible – the analog of one of the characterisations of Dedekind domains.

Actually, this ring is even more: it is a *Bézout domain*, i.e. every finitely generated ideal is principal.

You can find much more information in the Wikipedia notice on [Prüfer domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_domain).

Comment: Actually, we probably have more info here than does Wikipedia, e.g. see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14109/when-does-the-modular-law-apply-to-ideals-in-a-commutative-ring/14122#14122) for almost 30 characterizations of Prufer domains.