# How can I prove that $\gcd(a,b)=1\implies \gcd(a^2,b^2)=1$ without using prime decomposition?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

How can I prove that if $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $\gcd(a^2,b^2)=1$, without using prime decomposition?
I should only use definition of gcd, division algorithm, Euclidean algorithm and corollaries to those.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this homework? Here's a hint: by Euclid's algorithm, $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ if and only if there exist integers $x$ and $y$ with $ax+by=1$. Then $(ax+by)^2 = a^2(x^2) + b(2axy + by^2) = 1$. What can you conclude?

Comment: @user7530, this only shows that $gcd(a^2,b)=1$.  But Greg's hint to cube it worked for me.

Comment: @Dan Brumleve: user7530's hint applied twice (first for a, then for b) works too.

Comment: @user7530 +1 - Your comment is the best answer.

Comment: **Beware** that SE tweeted this post so it got much wider than normal exposure. As usual, this means that earlier and more elementary answers have a much higher number of votes than they normally would due to drive-by voting.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The golden rule for *all* problems about greatest common divisors, I claim (especially if you're specifically trying to avoid using prime decomposition), is the fact that $\gcd(a,b)$ is equal to the smallest positive integer $g$ that can be written in the form $g=ax+by$ with $x,y$ integers.

In particular, $\gcd(a,b)=1$ if and only if there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+by=1$. (This is not true with 1 replaced by a larger integer! It's true because 1 is the smallest positive integer there is.)

That's my general hint; my specific hint is to *cube* both sides of the equation $ax+by=1$.

Comment: +1 Incidentally, I've yet to see a proof using unique prime factorization that doesn't become a lot more elegant when you use this fact instead.

Comment: That is really helpful, thanks! I hadn't thought of cubing the equation; now I can factor $a^2$ or $b^2$ out of every term and get the linear combination I needed.

Comment: It is **misleading** to call this a "gcd golden rule" since it fails miserably in many  common non-Bezout UFDs, e.g. $\,\Bbb Z[x],\ \Bbb Q[x,y].\,$ But the result holds true here and can be proved very simply and more generally without using prime factorizations but instead using basic gcd laws - see my answer.

Answer (score 10):

This can actually be done in a strictly multiplicative structure, in which we might not have (or care about) addition.  In particular, let $M$ be a commutative cancellative [monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) under the operation $\cdot$.  In other words, for all $x,y,z\in M$, $x\cdot y = y\cdot x$ and if $x \cdot y=x \cdot z$ then $y=z$.  As is customary, from now on we'll write $xy$ instead of $x \cdot y$.

So, for $x,y\in M$, we say that $d\in M$ is a greatest common divisor of $x$ and $y$ if:

1. $d \mid x$ and $d \mid y$ (ie $d$ is a common divisor of $x$ and $y$), and
2. For all $d'\in M$ with $d'\mid x$ and $d' \mid y$, we have $d' \mid d$.

It is easy to prove that greatest common divisors are unique up to unit multiples (ie if $d_1$ and $d_2$ are greatest common divisors of $x$ and $y$, then there exists an invertible element $u\in M$ such that $x=uy$).*  With this caveat in mind, we'll use the notation $d=\gcd(x,y)$ to mean that $d$ is a greatest common divisor of $x$ and $y$.  Of course, saying $\gcd(x,y)=1$ really means that the only common divisors of $x$ and $y$ are units of $M$.

We say that $M$ is a **GCD-monoid** if every pair of elements in $M$ have a greatest common divisor.

So, with this definition (which reduces to Greg Martin's definition above in the case when we consider $M=\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ under multiplication), we first prove the following proposition.

**Proposition:**  Let $M$ be a GCD-monoid and $a,b\in M$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$.  Then, for any $c\in M$ with $a\mid bc$, we have $a \mid c$.

**Sketch of proof:**  We have $a\alpha =bc$ for some $\alpha\in M$.  Since $M$ is a GCD-monoid, let $d:=\gcd(b,\alpha)$.  Then,

$ad=\gcd(ab,a\alpha)=\gcd(ab,bc)=\gcd(a,c)b$.  However, since $d \beta =b$ for some $\beta\in M$, we have $\beta \mid a$ and $\beta \mid b$, hence $\beta$ is invertible in $M$, $a=\gcd(a,c)$, and $a \mid c$.  $\blacksquare$

(Note that I technically used the result that $x \cdot \gcd(y,z)=\gcd(xy,xz)$, but that can also be proved using the definition of gcd above.)

So, assume  $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and suppose we have a common divisor $x$ of $a^2$ and $b^2$.  So, $x\alpha=a^2$ and $x\beta=b^2$ for some $\alpha,\beta\in M$.  Then,

$x\alpha \beta = \beta a^2 = \alpha b^2$

whence $a \mid \alpha b^2$.  By the proposition above, $a \mid \alpha$, and it follows that $x \mid a$.  By a symmetric argument, $x \mid b$.  Therefore $x$ is an invertible element in $M$ and $\gcd(a^2,b^2)=1$.

In fact, you can use the same argument (with a bit more care) to show that $\gcd(a^m,b^n)=1$ for all $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$.

* - In the integers, the usual convention is to sidestep this by restricting greatest common divisors to be positive.  However, there are plenty of algebraic structures where there are more than two invertible elements.  In practice, the distinctions made amongst unit multiples of an element are often ignored.

Comment: Downvoter: Care to explain?

Answer (score 7):

Below are sketches of four proofs. Note: proofs cubing the Bezout gcd equation are a special case of the first proof below - which works more generally, e.g. in $\,\Bbb Z[x],\ \Bbb Q[x,y]$ - see "Beware" below.

---

**Hint** $\rm\,\ \color{#c00}{(a,b)} (a^2,b^2) = \color{#c00}{(a,b)}^3,\, $ true since both sides $\rm\: =\: (a^3,\,a^2b,\,ab^2,\,b^3)\, $ by applying basic gcd laws (distributive, commutative, associative), cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3635955/242). Cancelling $\,\rm \color{#c00}{(a,b)}\ne 0\,$ from both sides of above yields $\rm\, (a^2,b^2) = (a,b)^2.\,$ OP is special case $\,\rm (a,b)= 1.\,$

---

**Or** $\rm\, (a^2,b^2) = (a,b)^2,\,$ a gcd *Freshman's Dream,*  is provable by cancelling $\rm\,(a,b)^2\,$ to [reduce to case $\rm\,\,(a,b)=1\,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3471852/242) (OP). $ $  Then [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252748/242), i.e. $\rm\,(x,y)=1=(x,z)\,\Rightarrow\,(x,yz)=1,\,$ yields $\rm\,(a,b)=1\,\Rightarrow\,(a,b^2)=1\,\Rightarrow\,(a^2,b^2)=1\,$ (or we can prove it locally, i.e. one prime at a time: $ $ prime $\rm\,p\mid a^2,b^2\,\Rightarrow\,p\mid a,b,\,$ contra $\rm\,(a,b)=1)$.

---

**Or** Gauss's Lemma (GL) yields a quick proof. Let $\rm\:{\cal C}(f)\:$ denote the content of a polynomial, i.e. the gcd of its coefficients. GL $\rm\: \Rightarrow\ {\cal C}(f\:g)\ =\ {\cal C}(f)\ {\cal C}(g)\ $ so

$$\rm (a,b)^2\! =\ {\cal C}\:(ax\! +\! b)\ {\cal C}\:(a x\! -\! b)\, =\, {\cal C}\:((a x\! +\! b)(ax\! -\! b))\, =\, {\cal C}\:(a^2 x^2\! -\! b^2)\, =\, (a^2,b^2)\qquad$$

---

**More generally** [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10400/comaximal-ideals-in-a-commutative-ring/10416#10416) the *Freshman's Dream* $\rm\:(a,b)^n = (a^n,b^n),\,$ has a unified proof for arithmetic of GCDs and cancellable ideals using basic arithmetic laws (as in first proof above)

**Beware**  The first $2$ proofs above work in **every** gcd domain (domains where all gcds $\:\!(a,b)\:\!$ exist), but common proofs in $\,\Bbb Z\,$ via Bezout  **fail** to generalize to familiar UFDs like $\,\Bbb Z[x],\, \Bbb Q[x,y]\,$ where gcds generally do not have  linear (Bezout) form, e.g. in $\,\Bbb Q[x,y]\,$ we have $\,(x,y) = 1\,$ but this gcd is not of Bezout form, else  $\,x\:\!g(x,y) + y\:\! f(x,y) = 1,\,$ so eval at $\,x = y = 0\,$ yields $\,0 = 1.\,$ Ditto for $(2,x)$ in $\,\Bbb Z[x]$.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the following property to show $\gcd(a^{2},b^{2})=1$ if $\gcd(a,b)=1$.
$\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $\gcd(a,c)=1$ then $\gcd(a,bc)=1$.
Note that from this you can also see that $\gcd(a^{n},b^{n})=1$,

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume for the sake of contradiction that $\gcd(a^{2},b^{2}) \neq 1$.

Then there exists an integer $c > 0$ such that $c \mid a^{2}$ and $c \mid b^{2}$.

Now, let $p$ be any prime factor of $c$.

Hence, $p \mid a^{2}$ and $p \mid b^{2}$.

Therefore, $p \mid a$ and $p \mid b$, contracting the assumption that $\gcd(a, b) = 1.$