# Prove that $\gcd(a, b) = 1 ⇒ \gcd(a^2, b^2) = 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I have a question from a sample exam I find difficults to solve:

Prove that if $\gcd(a, b) = 1 ⇒ \gcd(a^2, b^2) = 1$ .

I don't have any idea how to start. I'd like to get helped. thanks!

Comment: What setting? Ordinary integers ($\mathbb{Z}$), a UFD, a general ring?

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked and answered here before, but how to find it?

Comment: And if over $\mathbb{Z}$, what sort of results were assumed known? Unique prime factorization?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prove that $\gcd(a,b)=1\implies \gcd(a^2,b^2)=1$ without using prime decomposition?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75676/how-can-i-prove-that-gcda-b-1-implies-gcda2-b2-1-without-using-prime-d) --- see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166839/if-gcda-b-1-then-gcdan-bn-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "trick" way is to solve $ax+by =1$ then cube both sides to get a solution to $a^2X+b^2Y=1$.

The reason I call this a "trick" is that the result generalizes to any UFD, but this proof does not.

Comment: This is an amazing trick I was not aware of, thanks!

Comment: Amm .. thanks. but why cube, and not square?

Comment: Because when you cube, all the terms are either divisible by $a^2$ or $b^2$. If you square, you are left with one term $2abxy$ which is not divisible by either, so you don't get a solution for $a^2X+b^2Y=1$.

Comment: Squaring, though, can be used to show that $(a,b)=1\implies (a^2,b)=1$. And then $(b,a^2)=1\implies (b^2,a^2)=1$. So you could go that route. Just requires an extra step.

Comment: Wow I got confused .. can you please some me an example? :S

Comment: For example: $1=(ax+by)^2 = a^2x^2 + 2axby + b^2y^2 = a^2(x^2) + b(2axy+by^2)$. Setting $X=x^2$ and $Y=2axy+by^2$, then $1=a^2X+bY$. So $(a^2,b)=1$. Again, this is the "trick" answer, it is better to try to understand the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

Let's think about the prime factors of $a$ and $b$. $\gcd(a,b)=1$ means that there's no common prime factor of $a$ and $b$. Now when we square $a$ and $b$ they have the same prime factors as before but twice all of them. As $a$ and $b$ has no common prime factor neither does $a^2$ and $b^2$. So $gcd(a^2,b^2)=1$ hence **PROVED** :)