# Prove $\gcd(a^3,b^3)$ = $\gcd(a,b)^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

$\gcd(a^3,b^3)$ = $\gcd(a,b)^3$

Let there be integers $s,t,x,y$

$a^3s + b^3t = (ax + by)^3 $

Should I start like from the above?

Comment: Best to consider prime factorisations instead.

Comment: If $c|d$ then $c^3|d^3$ and let c be the gcd in this case

Comment: First prove the case where $\gcd(a,b)=1$. You can do this by taking $(ax+by)^5=a^3X+b^3Y$. Then prove the general case from there.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75676/how-can-i-prove-that-gcda-b-1-implies-gcda2-b2-1-without-using-prime-d/75678#75678

Comment: @ThomasAndrews how would I prove for a general case?

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle ~ \gcd(a^3, b^3) = \prod_{1 \le k \le n} p_k^{\min(3r_k, 3s_k)} = \prod_{1 \le k \le n} p_i^{3\min(r_k, s_k)} = \bigg(\prod_{1 \le k \le n} p_i^{\min(r_k, s_k)} \bigg)^3 = (\gcd(a, b))^3.$