# Prove or disprove that $a$ and $b$ are coprime integers iff $a^2$ and $b^2$ are coprime integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove or disprove:
$\forall a,b\in \mathbb N  $, $a$ and $b$ are coprime integers IFF $a^2$ and $b^2$ are coprime integers.

I know how to prove that if $a$,$b$ are coprime integers but I have no clue how to prove the other way around to satisfy the IFF.

Comment: Hint: $p|a^2$ implies $p|a$.

Comment: Show what you've done so far, that way people have something to work with.

Comment: Go here $\longrightarrow$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939319/powers-of-coprime-numbers?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How to argue depends on what you know about coprime integers.

**I.**

For example, if you know that $a,b$ being coprime means that there are integers $n,m$ with 
 $$ an+bm=1, $$
you can argue as follows:

First, if $a^2$ and $b^2$ are coprime, as witnessed by integers $n,m$, so
 $$ a^2n+b^2m=1, $$
then $k=an$ and $l=bm$ witness that $a,b$ are coprime:
 $$ ak+bl=1. $$

The other direction is more interesting: First, note that if $x,y$ are coprime, so are $x^2,y$:
 $$ xn+ym=1\Longrightarrow (xn+ym)^2=1, $$
but $$ (xn+ym)^2= x^2 n^2+y(2xnm+ym^2)= x^2k+yl, $$
with $k=n^2$ and $l=2xnm+ym^2$.

This gives us that if $a,b$ are coprime, $a^2,b$ are coprime. But then, letting $x=b,y=a^2$, this gives us that $x^2=b^2$ and $y=a^2$ are coprime as well, as we wanted.

**II.**

On the other hand, if you know that being coprime can be verified in terms of common prime divisors, then the argument is simpler, because if $p$ is prime and $p|xy$ then $p|x$ or $p|y$. This means that for any prime $p$, we have that $p|a^2$ iff $p|a$, and the same with $b^2$ and $b$, so the prime divisors of $a^2,b^2$ are the same as those of $a,b$. Hence, one pair is coprime iff the other is coprime.

Comment: the definition of coprime integers I work with says that there's no $k\in \mathbb N >1$ that $k|a$ and $k|b$, that's it.

Comment: The Bezout two-step argument can be replaced by $1=(xn+ym)^3=x^3n^3+3x^2n^2ym+3xny^2m^2+y^3m^3=n^2(X)+m^2(Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

let $d|a$ and $d|b$ then $d^2|a^2$ and $d^2|b^2$. So - by considering the contrapositive - if $a^2$ and $b^2$ are coprime, $a$ and $b$ are.

If $a$ and $b$ are coprime then $a^2$ and $b^2$ must be too, if a prime $p|a^2$ then $p|a$ so if a prime divided $a^2$ and $b^2$ it would be a common factor of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\ (a,b)^2 = (a^2,b^2)\,$ by cancelling $\rm\,(a,b)\,$ in $\rm\ (a,b)^3 = (a^3, a^2 b, ab^2, b^3) = (a,b) (a^2, b^2).\:$
Hence $\rm\,(a,b)=1\iff (a^2,b^2) = 1.$

**Remark** $\ $  The proof utilizes only basic gcd laws (associative, commutative, distributive, etc), e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20904/23500) for background. It easily generalizes to the [Freshman's Dream](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/10416/23500) $\rm\: (a,b)^n = (a^n,b^n).\:$