# Product of two ideals in Dedekind domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, dedekind-domain

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be a Dedekind domain and $I=(x_1,\ldots, x_n),J=(y_1,\ldots, y_m)\subseteq \mathcal{O}$ two ideals. Is it possible, that $IJ\neq K$ with $K$ the ideal generated by the products $x_iy_j$?

For PID this is obvious and since a Dedekind Domain is PID iff it is UFD, most of the examples I have in mind don't work to disprove it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x_iy_j\in IJ$ for all $i,j$, and these generate $K$, we have $K\subseteq IJ$.

Since everything in $IJ$ is of the form $\sum a_ib_i$ with $a_i\in I, b_i\in J$, you can just rewrite the $a_i$ and $b_i$ in terms of the $x_i$ and $y_j$ , distribute everything, and wind up with a linear combination of $x_iy_j$. Thus $IJ\subseteq K$.

Answer (score 1):

It is an immediate inductive consequence of the Ideal Distributive Law $\, A(B+C) = AB + AC,\ $ which is true in any ring.

While you are thinking about the relationship with PIDs, note that the distributive law [also holds for gcds.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242) Therefore, by exploiting their  common arithmetical laws, one can often give unified proofs that work for both gcds and ideals. For example, see [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/10416/242) of the *Freshman's Dream for ideals/gcds $\,(A+B)^n = A^n+B^n,\,$ or $\,(a,b)^n = (a^n,b^n).$