# GCD and LCM of powers in GCD domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

Let $R$ be a [GCD domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain). This means that it is an integral domain in which any 2 elements have a GCD, and hence also an LCM.

Question:

> Is it true that if $z$ is a GCD or LCM of $x$ and $y$ in $R$, then $z^n$ is a GCD or LCM of $x^n$ and $y^n$ for any nonnegative integer $n$?

Remember that GCDs and LCMs are only defined up to associates.

Comment: See [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/10416/242).