# exercise in commutative algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

exercise: let $A$ be an integral domain in which all prime ideals are maximal (but may not be Dedekind in general).  let $P_1,  P_2$ be 2 distinct prime ideals.  prove: for any positive integer $m, n$,  $P_1^m+P_2^n=A$.

so the hint is to prove this first for arbitrary $m$ when $n=1$.  I finished this step by observing that if $P_1^m$ is contained in $P_2$,  then since they re prime ideals $P_1 \subset P_2$.  this contradicts the fact that they re distinguish and maximal.  so this was done.

but next how to use induction for $m$? I need some hint, thanks!

Comment: The $m=1$ case furnishes $a\in P_1$ and $b\in P_2$ with $a+b=1$.

Comment: oh from this we then use binomial expansion.  yes that's rightI'm a stupid beginner,  thank u so much

Comment: Duplicate of  [Comaximal ideals in a commutative ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10400/comaximal-ideals-in-a-commutative-ring)

Comment: An integral domain whose prime ideals are maximal is a field. Probably you wanted to say "all **non-zero** prime ideals are maximal".

Answer (score -1):

consider it to be true for n then multiply by P_2 
the RHS is going to be P_2.

see that (P_1)^m*(P_2) + (P_2)^(n+1) is contained in (P_2).

(P_1)^m*(P_2) is contained in (P_1)^m

(P_1)^m is not contained in (P_2)

now let "a" be any such element which is in (P_1)^m but not in (P_2)
note that (a) + (P_2) is contained in (a) + (P_1)^m*(P_2) + (P_2)^(n+1) hence (P_1)^m + (P_2)^(n+1)

and from maximality of (P_2) you get (a) + (P_2) is actually A