# Proving that $a,n$ and $b, n$ relatively prime implies $ab,n$ relatively prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

**Question**:

Suppose $a,b \in \Bbb N$, $\gcd (a,n) = \gcd(b,n) = 1$. The question is to prove or give a counterexample: $\gcd(ab,n) = 1$.

**My Work**:

This is what I have so far (for $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta \in \Bbb Z$): 
\begin{align*}
\gcd(a,n) = 1 \ &\Rightarrow 1 = \alpha a + \beta n\\
\gcd(b,n) = 1 \ &\Rightarrow 1 = \gamma b + \delta n
\end{align*}
Multiplying the top equation by $b$, and the bottom by $a$, I have $$ b + a = (\alpha + \gamma)ab + (\beta b + \delta a)n $$

Here is where I am stuck. I now know that you can write a linear combination of $ab, n$ in this form, where all coefficients are integers, but I think I may have gone down the wrong road in this proof in multiplying by $a,b$. Hints would be appreciated.

Comment: You question does not match your title. Should the question end $gcd(ab,n)=1$?

Comment: One of the points of this question is to stress that a number $g$ being the gcd of a set of numbers is usually a stronger requirement than being the gcd of any proper subset of them.

Comment: @jmi4 The first comment is correct. Does your question concern the statement in the title, or the different statement in the body?

Comment: Sorry everyone! The body is a typo. I mean the $\gcd(ab,n) = 1$

Comment: See also: [Prove that if $\gcd( a, b ) = 1$ then $\gcd( ac, b ) = \gcd( c, b ) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20889).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Note:** This answers a prior version of the question: does $(a,n)=1=(b,n)\Rightarrow (a,b)=1?$]

Let $a=2, b=4, n=5$ shows statement is false.

Comment: You could have $n=3$ too ...

Comment: Well...this is embarrassing. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkBennet Or any odd.

Comment: Indeed - I had your example first, and then I thought 3 was a lower number - and I put up a higher one in my answer simply as an invitation to think a bit about what the question meant.

Comment: Am I having a moment of stupidity or isnt gcd$(8,5) = 1$, supporting the claim?

Comment: I thought the gcd of any prime number and a number that isn't that number is 1...

Answer (score 8):

The following is an answer to the **question in the title**, using the technique that you tried to use. Of course the answer has nothing to do with the question in the body of the post.

Because $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime, there exist integers $q$ and $r$ such that $qa+rn=1$. Similarly, there exist integers $s$ and $t$ such that $sb+tn=1$. Rewrite these equations as $qa=1-rn$ and $sb=1-tn$. Multiply. We obtain
$$(qa)(sb)=(1-rn)(1-tn).$$
Expand and rearrange a bit. We get 
$$(qs)ab+(r+t-rtn)n=1,$$
which shows that $ab$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another simple solution for the question in the title.

Suppose by contradiction that $ab$ and $n$ are not relatively prime. Then they have a common **prime** divisor $p$.

Then $p$ divides $n$, and it also divides $ab$, hence either $a$ or $b$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $n=17$, I think you can try $a$ and $b$ less than 17 and coprime to 17, in fact because 17 is a prime ...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ By Euclid's Lemma, the naturals coprime to $\rm\:n\:$ are closed under multiplication. But sets $\rm\:S\ne \{1\}$ of positive naturals closed under multiplication always have non-coprime elements, e.g. $\rm\:1\ne a\in S\:\Rightarrow\:a^2\in S,\:$ so $\rm\:(a,a^2) = a \ne 1.$

As for Euclid's Lemma (the question in the title), by Bezout's Lemma, the elements coprime to $\rm\,n\,$ are exactly the invertible elements mod $\rm\,n,\,$ and $ $ *a product of invertibles is invertible,* thus

$$\rm (a,n) = 1 = (b,n)\:\Rightarrow\:\exists\, \bar a,\bar b:\ a\bar a\equiv 1 \equiv b\bar b\,\ (mod\ n)\: \Rightarrow\ ab\ \bar a\bar b\equiv 1\,\ (mod\ n)\:\Rightarrow\: (ab,n) = 1 $$

Answer (score 1):

Think in terms of the prime factorizations of $a,b$, and $n$. (It doesn’t matter whether you’ve proved unique factorization yet; this is just a way to approach the problem.) Let $A$ be the set of prime factors of $a$, $b$ the set of prime factors of $b$, and $N$ the set of prime factors of $n$. Your hypothesis is basically that $A\cap N=\varnothing=B\cap N$, and the question is whether this imlies that $A\cap B=\varnothing$. When you put the question this way, the answer is pretty easy to see: the fact that $A$ and $B$ are both disjoint from $N$ says nothing at all about whether $A$ and $B$ overlap. Indeed, if $A=B\ne\varnothing$ it’s automatic that $A$ and $B$ will overlap. This immediately points you towards a counterexample like i.m. soloveichik’s. It actually gives you an even simpler one: just let $a=b=2$ and $n=1$!