# Is the product of two coprime numbers coprime with a third if the three numbers are pairwise coprime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

I have some trouble finding a proof for the following:

Let $a, b$ and $ c $   be three pairwise coprime integers.

Is $ab$  coprime with $c$? If yes, how to prove it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Suppose there is a prime $p$ dividing $c$ and $ab$ …

Comment: See [Proving that $a,n$ and $b, n$ relatively prime implies $ab,n$ relatively prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/189401) or [Prove that if $\gcd( a, b ) = 1$ then $\gcd( ac, b ) = \gcd( c, b ) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20889) and [many other posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/20889)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_i$ be the prime factors of $a$,  $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_j$ be the prime factors of $b$, $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_k$ be the prime factors of $c$. All of these primes are distinct (because $a,b,c$ are pairwise coprime). When you multiply $b \times c$ the new product has the prime factors $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_j, c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_k$. None of these prime factors are in $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_i$. Therefore, $b\times c$ is coprime with $a$.

Comment: There is probably a neater solution, but this one is a little more intuitive. The product $b\times c$ cannot have a "new" prime factor that was not in b or c. Therefore, it must be coprime with a.

Answer (score 10):

More generally, if $\gcd(a,c)=1$ and $\gcd(b,c)=1$ then $\gcd(ab,c)=1$. This can be proved by solving:

$$ax+cy=1\\bu+cv=1\tag{1}$$

then multiply these two equations to get:

$$ab(xu)+c(axv+byu+cyv)=1$$

(1) can be solved by [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Comment: Does (ax+cy)(bu+cv) really give the left side of the last equation ?

Comment: Thanks, @FabriceTixador Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to invoke the fact that the GCD function is multiplicative ([ProofWiki has one proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/GCD_is_Multiplicative)): given $b$ and $c$ coprime, $$\gcd(a, bc) = \gcd(a, b) \gcd(a, c).$$ Therefore, if $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(a, c) = \gcd(b, c) = 1$, then $\gcd(ab, c) = 1$ as well.

Answer (score 3):

They are co prime as well:

$(a, b) = 1, (b, c) = 1 \ \ \ (1)$

$[a, b] = a * b \ \ \ (2)$

$(1)=>([a, b], c) = 1$

$(2)=>(a * b, c) = 1$