# Let a, b, c be integers with at most one of the three equal to 0. Prove that if gcd(a,c)=1, then gcd(ab,c)=gcd(b,c).

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

So far I have two strategies in mind for proving this:

1) Bezout’s Identity: 
ax+cy=1 --> bax+bcy=b ==> gcd(ab,bc)=b

2)Properties of Prime numbers: if gcd(a,c)=1, then a and c do not share any prime factors

Both ideas have left me at a dead end

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: **Hint** $ $ By the [gcd distributive law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242) we can cancel $\,(b,c)\,$ reducing to the case $\,(b,c)=1\,$ below $$ (a,c)=1=(b,c)\,\Rightarrow\, (ab,c) = 1\qquad\qquad$$ or, said in coprimality language: $\,a,b\,$ coprime to $\,c\ \Rightarrow\ ab\,$ coprime to $\,c\ \ \ $

Comment: If you don't know how to prove the above simpler reduced case then e.g. [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/189425/242)

Answer (score 0):

One place to start answering this is, given that $\gcd(a,c)=1$ what can you say about the common factors of $ab$ and $c$.

Try proving the statement that $\gcd(a,c) = 1$ and $a|bc$ implies that $a|b$. Proving this statement should put you on the right track for finding the solution to this problem.

Comment: Please try to precede 'gcd' with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

1) There exist $x,y$ so that $ax + cy=1$ and there are $k,j$ so that $bk + cj=\gcd(b,c)$ so $1*(bk+cj)= (ax + cy)(bk+cj)=abxk + c(ybk+ajx+cyj) =   \gcd(b,c)$.

So $\gcd(ab,c) |\gcd(b,c)$ and clearly $\gcd(b,c)|\gcd(ab,c)$ so $\gcd(ab,c)=\gcd(b,c)$

2) $a$ and $c$ don't share any prime factors.  SO the only prime factor $c$ shares with $ba$ are the prime factors it shares with $b$ so $\gcd(ba,c)=\gcd(b,c)$.

More formally.  Let $\gcd(b,c) = d$ and $b=b'd$ and $c = c'd$.  Then it's easy and standard to show that $c',b'$ are relatively prime [$\gcd(b',c')*d$ is a common divisor of $b$ and $c$ but $d$ is the *greatest* common divisor].

You should have proven somewhere that $\gcd(ma,mb)= m\gcd(a,b)$.  [($m\gcd(a,b)$ is a common divisor clearly, yet any larger divisor would require taking a common factor from $\frac a{\gcd(a,b)}$ and $\frac b{\gcd(a,b)}$ and there are no common factors left.]

So $\gcd(ab, c) = \gcd(ab'd,c'd) = d\gcd(ab',c')= d*1$.