# Show that $(a+b)^{\phi(a)\phi(b)}\equiv(a^{\phi(b)}+b^{\phi(a)})\pmod{ab}$.

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

The problem:
For all positive integers $a$ and $b$, if $(a, b)=1$, then $(a+b)^{\phi(a)\phi(b)}\equiv(a^{\phi(b)}+b^{\phi(a)}) \pmod{ab}$.

My work thus far.
I know that by using Euler's theorem I can show that $(a^{\phi(b)}+b^{\phi(a)})\equiv1 \pmod{ab}$.

I am currently stuck trying to show that $(a+b)^{\phi(a)\phi(b)}\equiv1\pmod{ab}$, and then putting that with my idea above to complete the proof. 
Can anyone give me any hints or let me know if I am on the right track? Thanks!

Comment: Immediate by Euler's little Theorem and CRT.

Comment: Could you provide a hint as to how I would apply the CRT? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could you provide a hint as to how I would apply the CRT?

$\!\bmod \color{#c00}a\!:\,\ c:= (\color{#c00}a\!+\!b)^{\phi(b)\phi(a)}\equiv (b^{\phi(b)})^{\phi(a)}\equiv 1\ $ by Euler-phi, by $\,\gcd(b^{\phi(b)},a)=1$

By symmetry, also $\,c\equiv 1\pmod{\!b},\,$ thus $\,c\equiv 1\pmod{\!ab}\,$ by [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242)

**Remark** $ $ Equivalently, by Euler,  $\,\rm LHS-RHS \equiv 1-1\equiv 0\,$ both  mod $\,a\,$ & $b,\,$ so it is divisible by $a$ and $b,\,$ so also by their lcm $= ab$, by $\,a,b\,$ coprime, i.e. $\,{\rm LHS\equiv RHS}\pmod{\!ab}$

Comment: Oh okay, that is much more clear. Thank you.

Comment: @MiltonP. I added another way to view it

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Show that 
$$(a+b)^{\phi(a)\phi(b)}\equiv(a^{\phi(b)}+b^{\phi(a)})\pmod a$$
and
$$(a+b)^{\phi(a)\phi(b)}\equiv(a^{\phi(b)}+b^{\phi(a)})\pmod b$$

Comment: Ahh I see. So it would be similar to showing that $(a^{\phi(b)}+b^{\phi(a)})\equiv1\,(mod\,ab)$, right?

Comment: See my edits to this answer for proper MathJax usage.

Answer (score 1):

First, $(a,b)=1\implies \phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$.

Second, $(a,b)=1\implies (ab,a+b)=1$.  You can do this by first noting that $(a,a+b)=1=(b,a+b)$.  Then apply [Proving that $a,n$ and $b, n$ relatively prime implies $ab,n$ relatively prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/189401).

Now you can apply Euler's theorem.