# how do we prove $p|q\cdot r \rightarrow p=q$ or $p=r$ (all primes)?

Tags: arithmetic

I know this is one of the most fundamental basis of arithmetic but I can't find the result by myself.

how do we prove $p|q\cdot r\rightarrow p=q$ or $p=r$? ($p, q, r$ being prime numbers)

Comment: I think this question is much harder than it looks.  If you use the uniqueness of prime factorization, then you end up with a circular argument.  Because how do you prove uniqueness of prime factorization?  I struggled with this question for several days.  I ended up using Euclid's algorithm for finding the highest common factor.  But I would have to rack my brain to remember how it went.

Comment: Looking back in my old answers, I see that this question is very closely related to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/194259).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $p\mid q$, we are done.

Suppose that $p\not\mid q$. Since $p$ is only divisible by itself and $1$, $\gcd(p,q)=1$. By [Bezout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), there are $a$ and $b$ so that
$$
ap+bq=1\tag{1}
$$
Multiply $(1)$ by $r$ to get
$$
(ar)p+b(qr)=r\tag{2}
$$
Since $p\mid qr$, there is a $k$ so that $kp=qr$. Using this in $(2)$ gives
$$
r=p(ar+bk)\tag{3}
$$
which says that $p\mid r$.

QED

Comment: And Bezout's identity follows from Euclid's algorithm for HCF, doesn't it?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: Yes, but it can also be shown using the properties of a Euclidean domain without first proving the Euclidean algorithm. I do so in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/124991).

Comment: Well I don't see how you can prove the properties of a Euclidean domain without invoking the algorithm in some form.  (Using induction or a well-ordering principle may, in effect, be the same as invoking the algorithm.)

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: To implement Euclid's Algorithm, we need to know that we can divide, getting a quotient and remainder. That means we are assuming that we are in a Euclidean domain before we use the Euclidean Algorithm. Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 3):

The fully rigorous chain of proofs actually follows the following order:

You can prove the *division algorithm* using base axioms of the natural numbers (commutativity, distributivity, associativity, multiplicative identity, well-ordering principle), which is the claim that, given $a,b\in\Bbb N$, there exist $q,r\in\Bbb N$ such that $a=bq+r$ and $0\leq r<|b|$.  This easily generalizes to $\Bbb Z$.

From there, you can prove that *Linear Diophantine Equations* always have a solution: given $a,b\in\Bbb Z$, there exist $x,y\in\Bbb Z$ such that $ax+by=\gcd(a,b)$.

After you've proven this, what you're looking for is easy to prove.  Consider $a,b,c\in\Bbb N$ such that $a|bc$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$.  Then there exist $x,y\in \Bbb Z$ such that $ax+by=1$, or $acx+bcy=c$.  Note that, since $a|bc$, $\exists k\in \Bbb Z$ such that $ak=bc$, so we have $acx+aky=a(cx+ky)=c$.  Since $cx+ky$ is an integer by closure under addition and multiplication, $a|c$.

Note: unique prime factorization, as assumed by other answers, is **not** an axiom of the integers. Sure, it's perfectly okay to use it most of the time, but it is in fact a **consequence** of this chain of reasoning, and it's always best to be fully rigorous.  Luckily, RobJohn did it the right way.

(Ask if you want proofs of the first two; that would take a bit longer).

Answer (score 0):

Hint : what are prime divisors of $q \cdot r$ ?

Comment: Answering a question with a question... shaky ground, you might consider adding wording that describes your answer as a hint rather than risking downvotes...

Comment: its a question. but diluted one. its a hint no?

Comment: the answer to your hint is based on the question I am asking, isn't it ? :)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually almost axiomatic, but you just have to consider the prime factors of $qr$, which are $q$ and $r$. Therefore - if $p$ divides $qr$ one of them have to be equal to $p$, since unique factorisation holds in $\Bbb Z$.