# Gcd and lcm of $a_1, a_2, \dots,a_n$ exist in $R$ when $R$ is a UFD.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, euclidean-algorithm

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $a_1, a_2, \dots,a_n \in R - \{0\}$. Then to find the gcd and lcm of $a_1, a_2, \dots,a_n$ and they exist in $R$ when $R$ is a UFD.

We can express $a_1, a_2, \dots,a_n$ uniquely as finite product of irreducible elements as:

$a_1 \sim p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2} \dots p_n^{r_n} $, $a_2 \sim p_1^{s_1}p_2^{s_2} \dots p_n^{s_n}$ , $\dots,$ $a_n \sim p_1^{t_1}p_2^{t_2} \dots p_n^{t_n}$

Now, we define:

$\gcd (a_1, a_2, \dots,a_n ) = p_1^{c_1}p_2^{c_2} \dots p_n^{c_n}$ where $c_i = \min\{r_i,s_i,...,t_i\}$ and,

$lcm(a_1, a_2, \dots,a_n ) = p_1^{d_1}p_2^{d_2} \dots p_n^{d_n}$ where $d_i = \max\{r_i,s_i,...,t_i\}$

I can intuitively define them but how can I prove that they exist in $R$?

Please Help!

Comment: Well, those formulas are in $R$ by definition, since $R$ is closed under multiplication and $p_i$ are in $R$. The real question you need to prove is, why are these the GCD and LCM.

Comment: Incidentally, you might want to stick first with $n=2$ and then prove for general $n$ inductively, showing $\gcd(a_1,\dots a_n)=\gcd(\gcd(a_1,\cdots,a_{n-1}),a_n)$ and likewise for LCM.

Comment: can you please help in showing that

Comment: The expressions are not unique, unless the you assume for each $i$ that one if $r_i,s_i,\dots,t_i$ is non-zero. You definitely can't assume they are all non-zero...

Answer (score 2):

By existence and uniqueness of prime factorizations, divisibility [reduces](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252822/242) to divisibility in each prime component, i.e. $\ p^{\large a} q^{\large a'}\!\cdots\mid p^{\large b} q^{\large b'}\!\cdots\!\iff p^{\large a}\mid p^{\large b},\,\ q^{\large a'}\!\mid q^{\large b'},\,\ldots\ $

So $\,\ a\mid b,c\iff p^{\large a}\mid p^{\large b},p^{\large c},\ \ q^{\large a'}\mid q^{\large b'},q^{\large c'},\ldots\ $  each which obey

$$\quad\ \ \ \ \ \ p^{\large a}\mid p^{\large b},p^{\large c}\! \iff  a\le b,c \iff a\le \min\{b,c\} \iff  p^{\large a}\mid p^{\large \min\{b,c\}}$$

$\!\begin{align}{\rm So}\ \ a\mid b,c&\iff p^{\large a}\mid p^{\large \min\{b,c\}},\ q^{\large a'}\mid q^{\large \min\{b',c'\}}\ldots\\[.5em]
&\iff a\mid  \color{#c00}{p^{\large \min\{b,c\}}  q^{\large \min\{b',c'\}}}\ldots \end{align}$

**Remark** $\ $ Above we employ the [universal characterization / definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189430/242) of  gcd and lcm, i.e.

$$\begin{align}   a\mid b,c\iff a\mid \color{#c00}{\gcd(b,c)}\\
b,c\mid a\iff {\rm lcm}(b,c)\mid a\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

The $ $  lcm $ $  case is just the dual $\, \ b,c\mid a\iff \cdots,\ $ by reversing divisiblities in the gcd proof.