# Prove $\forall a,b,c \in \Bbb{Z} : \gcd(a,bc) | \gcd(a,b)\cdot\gcd(a,c)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm having trouble proving this statement:

$\forall a,b,c \in \Bbb{Z} : \gcd(a,bc) | \gcd(a,b)\cdot\gcd(a,c)$,

*without* using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (hasn't been taught yet).

---

What I've tried is to use the basic properties of GCD to come up with some equations to manipulate, but it hasn't lead to any useful result.

Let $x=\gcd(a,bc), y=\gcd(a,b), z=\gcd(a,c)$. Then $x|a$ and $x|bc$ etc. Need to manipulate this somehow to show $x|yz$, i.e. $\exists q \in \Bbb{Z} : qx=yz$.

What would be a reasonable next step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by Bezout's Theorem, there exist integers $s$ and $t$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=as+bt$. Similarly, there exist integers $u$ and $v$ such that  $\gcd(a,c)=au+cv$.

Expand the product $(as+bt)(au+cv)$.  We get an expression  of the shape $ax+bcy$ for some integers $x$ and $y$.

Now if $e$ divides both $a$ and $bc$, then $e$ divides $ax+bcy$.

Comment: Perfect, I knew there was some simple way to do this. I had something similar written down, but missed the last little bit.

Answer (score 0):

From my [post last week.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/289165/23500)

**Theorem** $\rm\qquad gcd(bc,a)\,|\,\gcd(b,a)\,gcd(c,a)$

$\begin{eqnarray}\rm{\bf Proof}\qquad\quad\ \ gcd(b,a) &=&\ \, \ \rm j\:b+m\:a \quad \!for\ some\,\ j,m\in \Bbb Z\ \ by\ Bezout\\
\rm gcd(c,a) &=&\ \ \rm k\:c+\ n\:a \quad for\ some\,\ k,n\in \Bbb Z\ \ by\ Bezout\\
\rm\ \  \Rightarrow\ \  gcd(b,a)\,gcd(c,a) &=&\:\rm  jk\,\color{#C00}{bc}\:+\:\color{#C00}a\,(\cdots)\ \ \ for\, \ \ (\cdots)\in \Bbb Z
\end{eqnarray}$

Since $\rm\:gcd(bc,a)\,|\,\color{#C00}{bc,a},\:$ it divides the right-side of prior, so also the left. $\ $ **QED**

More explicitly [one may prove,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/279782/23500) writing $\rm\,(x,y)\,$ for $\rm\,gcd(x,y)$

$$\rm (a,b)(a,c)\, =\, (a,bc)\,(a,b,c,bc/(a,bc)) $$