# Show $\,m$ odd $\Rightarrow \gcd(a^m-1,a^n+1)=1$ or $2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Let $(2^m-1,2^n+1)=1$ and suppose $m$ is even.  Also, $m,n,k\in \mathbb{N}$.  We have
$$(2^{m}-1)x+(2^n+1)y=1$$
$$(2^{2k}-1)x+(2^n+1)y=1$$
$$(2^{2k}-1)y\equiv 1\pmod{2^n+1}$$
$$(2^k+1)(2^k-1)y\equiv 1\pmod{2^n+1}$$
I don't know now to proceed from here....

Comment: It looks like you're trying to prove the wrong thing. You want to show that if $m$ is odd, then $(2^m-1,2^n+1)=1$. But you've started by assuming that the equation is true ...

Comment: Also, what is $n$?

Comment: n is just a positive integer.  I was trying to prove by contradiction.

Comment: The title says $m$ should be odd, but the post starts with "suppose $m$ is even". Which is it?

Comment: Okay. For a contradiction, you just need to reverse your train of thought: suppose $m$ is odd, but $(2^m-1,2^n+1) \neq 1$. Do you see the difference?

Comment: @Théophile, I think so...I'm going to try and run through it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

${d\mid\color{#0a0}{a^{\large m}\!-\!1}},\color{#90f}{a^{\large n}\!+\!1}\,$
$\Rightarrow\,
 {\rm mod}\ d\!:\,\color{#0a0}{a^{\large m}\! \equiv}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\overset{\Large\ [\,\color{#90f}{ -1\ \equiv\ a^{\LARGE n}}]^{\LARGE\color{#c00}2}\ \ \ \ }{ 1\color{#c00}{\equiv {\color{#90f}{a^{\large \color{#c00}2n}}}}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!$
$\Rightarrow
 {\rm ord}\,a\:\!|\:\!\overbrace{(\color{#0a0}m,\color{#90f}{\color{#c00}2n})\!=\! (m,n)}^{\Large{\rm\ \ by}\ \color{#0a0}m\ \rm odd}\:\!|\:\!\color{#c00}n\,$
$\Rightarrow 
 \overbrace{\color{#c00}{\bf 1}\equiv\color{#90f}{a^{\large\color{#c00} n}\!\equiv -1}}^{\color{#08f}{\!\!\!\!\!\!\Large\Rightarrow\,\ d\ \mid\  2^{\phantom{|^|}}}}$

So either they are coprime, or they have $\color{#08f}{{\rm gcd}\,\ d = 2}\ (\!\iff\! a\,$ is odd).

**Remark** $ $ It's $\:\!\color{#0a0}m$ odd, $\:\!\color{#c00}{k\!=\!2}\,$ case of $\,\rm\color{#00f}E$ = [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20904/242) in the *exponents* below

**Lemma** $\,\ $ If $\ (\color{#0a0}m,\color{#c00}k)=1\,$ then $\, a^{\large\color{#0a0}m}\equiv 1\equiv a^{\large\color{#c00}{k}\:\!n}\, $ $\Rightarrow\, a^{\large n}\equiv 1$

**Proof** $\ \ {\rm ord}\ a\mid m,kn\, \Rightarrow\, {\rm ord}\ a\mid \underbrace{(\color{#0a0}m,\color{#c00}kn)\!\overset{\rm\color{#00f}E}=\!(m,n)}_{\large (\color{#0a0}m,\,\color{#c00}k)\,=\,1\qquad\!}\mid n\,\Rightarrow\, a^{\large n}\equiv 1$

The same idea occurs frequently in various guises, e.g. below is a fractional form.

**Lemma** $ $ If a fraction is writable with denominator $\,m\,$ and also with denominator $\,kn\,$ where $(\color{#0a0}m,\color{#c00}k)=1$ then the fraction can  be written with denominator $\,n$.

**Proof** $ $ Recall that the *least* denominator $\,d\,$ [divides every other denominator](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4491/242) hence, just as above,
$d\mid m,kn\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid (\color{#0a0}m,\color{#c00}kn) \overset{\rm\color{#00f}E}= (m,n)\mid n\ $ so $\,d\mid n,\,$ therefore scaling the fraction with least denominator $\,d\,$ by $\,n/d\,$ yields an equivalent fraction with denominator $\,n$.

---

**Alternatively** we could [employ  $\,(a^m-1,a^j-1) = a^{(m,j)}-1\ $](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/7561/242) (for $\,j=kn),\,$ whose proof is exactly the same as in the above Lemma, using divisibility by $\:\!{\rm ord}\, a$.

We can abstract out these similarities and present unified proofs after we have studied the
pertinent algebraic structures: $ $ *ideals* and *modules* (viz. [order ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+%22order+ideals%22) and  [denominator ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+%22denominator+ideals%22))

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2983281/242) for $\,(a^m+1,a^n+1)$ $\ \ $