# If $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then $\gcd(2^m+1,2^n+1)\in\{1,3\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Let $m,n \in \Bbb{N}$ and  $\gcd(m,n)=1$, now prove 
$$\gcd\left(2^m +1 ,2^n +1\right)=1$$
 and show it is necessary that $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

I think that for second part of my question we can consider $m=6 ,n=2 ,\gcd(6,2)=2$ and further $2^6 +1 =65 ,2^2 +1 =5$ and $\gcd(65,5)=5$.

Comment: The second part seems all right.

Comment: The first part isn't true. If $m$ and $n$ are odd (and coprime), then $3$ must be a factor of both $2^m + 1$ and $2^n + 1$.

Comment: Yes .first part is false.thanks.

Comment: But the first part is true if $m,n$ aren't both odd. It's because $\gcd\left(2^m+1,2^n+1\right)\mid 2^{\gcd(m,n)}+1$.

Comment: @user236182.please more details.

Comment: http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~lavric/Santos%20-%20Number%20Theory%20for%20Mathematical%20Contests.pdf

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875940/show-2m-1-2n1-1-if-m-is-odd/876013#876013

Comment: @RaziehNoori .very thanks.

Comment: you're welcome, dear

Comment: I've edited the question, but made the title different from the actual question. It's because more people will benefit from it. Hopefully you're ok with it.

Answer (score 1):

The second part is false. $\gcd\left(2^4+1,2^2+1\right)=1$, but $\gcd(4,2)=2\neq 1$.

The first part is true if and only if $m,n$ are not both odd.

**Fact:** $\gcd\left(2^m+1,2^n+1\right)\mid 2^{\gcd(m,n)}+1$ (proof below).

If $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then $\gcd\left(2^m+1,2^n+1\right)\mid 3$.

If $m,n$ are both odd, $\gcd=3$, otherwise $\gcd=1$.

**Proof:** We want to prove that if $p^{\alpha}\mid 2^m+1, 2^n+1$, then $p^{\alpha}\mid 2^{\gcd(m,n)}+1$.

We know $p^{\alpha}\mid 2^{2m}- 1, 2^{2n}-1$, so by [this lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1):

$$p^{\alpha}\mid 2^{2\gcd(m,n)}- 1\iff p^\alpha\mid \left(2^{\gcd(m,n)}+1\right)\left(2^{\gcd(m,n)}-1\right)$$

We also know $p^{\alpha}\nmid 2^{\gcd(m,n)}-1$, because otherwise

$$p^{\alpha}\mid \left(2^{\gcd(m,n)}-1\right)\left(2^{m-\gcd(m,n)}+2^{m-\gcd(m,n)-1}+\cdots+1\right)=2^m-1,$$

contradiction. Also $\gcd\left(2^{\gcd(m,n)}+1,2^{\gcd(m,n)}-1\right)=1$. Therefore:

$$p^{\alpha}\mid 2^{\gcd(m,n)}+1$$