# What is $\gcd(61^{610}+1,61^{671}-1)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I implemented Extended Euclid Algorithm in c++ to solve this problem. Any approaches that you could it by hand.

$\gcd(61^{610}+1,61^{671}-1)=\ ?$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I used Extended Euclid Algorithm to solve this problem" -- ... is this not a mathematical approach??

Comment: Do some research on Chinese Remainder Theorem. Moreover, as a hint: $ 610+61=671$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I programmed it in c++,

Comment: ... and? That doesn't mean it's not inherently mathematical. If you were determined enough, you could've done it by hand - computers are just faster and less prone to mistakes/distraction/bodily needs. You're going to have to make clearer what you mean by this "some mathematical approach" thing if you want any meaningful help.

Comment: Sub-problem of a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3154020/242) a day prior (with $51$ changed to $61$, which makes no difference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely use Euclid's algorithm (but you won't need the extended version); it's just you also need some more *insight* into the numbers you're working with. Define $n:=61^{61}$ so your problem is computing $$(n^{11}-1,\,n^{10}+1)=(n^{10}+1,\,n+1)=(n+1,\,2)=2.$$

Comment: $$61^{610} , 61^{671}$$ are odd so $$61^{610}  + 1, 61^{671} - 1$$ are even and we can say that 2 is a factor of both, but to prove 2 is gcd I have to prove that there is no other common factor how should i prove it?

Comment: @ChandanKumar I just showed you how. Since $d$ is a common divisor of $ka+r,\,a$ iff it is of $a,\,r$, these pairs have the same gcd. Therefore, we eventually reduce the problem to $(n+1,\,2)$, which is $2$ because $2$ isn't big enough to have any larger factors.

Comment: thanks a lot for this elegant solution.

Comment: @Chandan You can do such problems very easily if you master modular arithmetic, e.g. see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3154151/242) and the answers linked there.