# Little confusion about the greatest common divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra, gcd-and-lcm

[Note: question was updated and clarified so comments & answer are a bit out of sync - Bill D.]

I have little confusion about the claim (ii) below. Although the claim  employs the hypothesis $\gcd(b,c)=1$, I think I have proved it without this, but I know that without $(b,c)=1$ this is not true. My question is: why was I able to prove it without this hypothesis?

> For $a, b, c \in \mathbb Z$, prove that
>
> ii. if $\gcd(b, c) = 1$, then $\gcd(a, bc) = \gcd(a, b)\gcd(a, c)$

This is the way i tried to prove this:

[image]

Comment: $(a,b)(a,c) = (a\color{#c00}{(a,b,c)},bc)\ [= (a,bc)\,$ if  $\,\color{#c00}{(a,b,c) = 1}].\ $ Is that what you mean by "proved without $\,(b.c) = 1?$

Comment: Please show your proof of ii that does not depend on $(b,c)=1$.  Consider $a=4,b=4,c=4$ where $(a,bc)=(4,16)=4, (a,b)(a,c)=(4,4)(4,4)=16$

Comment: I post a picture the way i tried to prove this

Comment: For i., if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $b|a$ then $|b|$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b,$ so $|b|\le \gcd(a,b)=1.$

Comment: Please anyone tells me why my way is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Theorem** $\ \ (a,b)(a,c)\, =\, \overbrace{(a,bc)}^{\large e}\iff \color{#c00}{(a,b,c,bc/e) = 1}\ \,$ [e.g. if $\,(a,b)= 1$]

$\begin{align}{\bf Proof}\quad\ \ \ (a,b)(a,c)\, &=\, ((a,b,c)a,\,bc)\\[.2em]
&=\, e\,((a,b,c)\color{#0a0}{a/e,\,bc/e})\\[.2em]
&=\, e\,\color{#c00}{((a,b,c),\,bc/e)}\,\ \ {\rm by}\, \ \ (\color{#0a0}{a/e,bc/e}) = (a,bc)/e = 1
\end{align}$

The first equality is by [gcd "polynomial" arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20904/242), i.e. applying the gcd associative, commutative and distributive laws. The second equality factors out $\,e\,$ using the gcd distributive law, and the final equality uses a version of [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20904/242).

**Remark** $ $ Replying to a query in a comment: an  error in your argument is the following inference

$$(a,b)(a,c) = n_0 a + y_0 bc\ \Rightarrow\ n_0 a + y_0 bc = (a,bc) $$

But  those coef's $\,n_0, y_0\,$ need not be the same as the Bezout coef's for $(a,bc).\,$ So your argument with no hypotheses on $\,a,b,c\,$ fails (as we know it must by the above theorem).

Comment: Why is my way wrong?

Comment: @Akalanka Why do you think your way is wrong?  Your question does not ask about your way. Instead it asks how to prove it without using $\,(b,c)= 1,\,$ which is what I did above, showing that it holds more generally if $\,(a,\color{#c00}{b,c},bc/e) = 1\ \ $ Yoru case $\,(\color{#c00}{b,c})=1\,$ is a special case.

Comment: Of course but i proved this without that property

Comment: @Akalanka See the Remark for one error.

Comment: Thanks i got it