# Divisors of $z$ and $m$ compared to divisors of $z$ and $mn$, where $(m,n) = 1$.

Tags: divisibility

Suppose $(m,n)=1$. Then is it true that the common divisors of $z$ and $m$ are exactly the common divisors of $z$ and $mn$? If not, is it true that the second set is a subset of the first? This is probably a very simple question, but I cannot get my mind around it atm. Thanks!

Edit: We have $z<m$, $z<n$ and $(z,n)=1$

Comment: What if $z=n{}$?

Comment: Did you mean to also assume that $\gcd(z,n)=1$?  Otherwise, you should easily be able to find counterexamples.

Comment: @lulu yes, please see edit.

Comment: You don't need to make the assumptions regarding inequalities. Since $\gcd(z,n)=1$ we see that $\gcd(z,mn)=\gcd(z,m)$  (see, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/prove-that-if-gcd-a-b-1-then-gcd-ac-b-gcd-c-b)) and the desired claim follows at once.

Answer (score 0):

Note $\ d\mid z,m\iff d\mid (z,m) := g\ $ by the [gcd Universal Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3356075/242)

and $\ d\mid z,nm\iff d\mid (z,nm) = g (z/g,\, n\:\!m/g) = g(z/g,n),\, $ by $(z/g,m/g)=1\,$ & [Euclid.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/prove-that-if-gcd-a-b-1-then-gcd-ac-b-gcd-c-b)

So they're equivalent $\iff (z/g,n) = 1,\,$ which is true when $(z,n)=1$.