# Number theory question involving prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Question :- $A=k^2-1$ and $B=(k+1)^2-1$, where k is a natural number greater than 1. How many prime numbers are there by which both A and B are divisible for at least 1 value of k ?

---

I attempted this question by plugging different kinds of numbers from the families of primes into k

For instance, k to be a one of the number from Family of $2$ ($2n,2n+1$) then from Family of $3$ ($3n,3n+1,3n+2$)

For $k=3n+1$, I was able to get both A and B a multiple of $3$ , hence by hit and trial I confirmed $3$ to be one of the prime number by which A and B will be divisible, with k being of type $3n+1$

Now for how many prime numbers do I need to do the same thing $5$ $(5n+1,5n+2,5n+3,5n+4)$,$7$ $( 7n+1,7n+2,7n+3,7n+4,7n+5,7n+6)...$ ? How to solve the question efficiently?

Comment: Have you tried any examples?  I think I quick search should tell you what $\gcd(A,B)$ must be.  Of course, you'll then have to prove that.

Comment: gcd $((k-1)*(k+1), k*(k+2))$ = gcd$(k-1,k+2)$ = gcd$(k-1,3)$ , is it correct ?  I don't know what would be the gcd of this final expression , and how would gcd help us in solving this question ?

Comment: Well, if the gcd is a divisor of $3$ then you have just eliminated every prime except $3$.

Comment: Thank you @lulu, but I am not sure if the expression of $gcd(k−1,k+2)$ is correct or not, could you please check if my reasoning for coming up with that expression is right or wrong :- Since, gcd$(k,k+1)=1$ , so $k+1$ will not contribute to the gcd , hence my updated expression will become gcd$(k-1,k*(k+3))$, then similarly gcd$(k−1,k)=1$, hence $k$ will not contribute to the gcd, therefore we would finally be left with gcd$(k−1,k+2)$ ?

Comment: Oh, yes. You are correct. The gcd is 3 if k=3n+1, and 1 otherwise

Comment: [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20889/242) & $\color{#c00}{(k,k^2\!-\!1)\!=\!1}\Rightarrow $ $(\color{#c00}{k^2\!-\!1,k}(k\!+\!2)) = (\color{#0a0}{k^2\!-\!1},\color{#90f}{k\!+\!2}) \overset{\rm\color{#0a0}R}= (\color{#0a0}3,k\!+\!2),\,$ where the final equality follows by employing $\rm\color{#0a0}{R}$ = [gcd mod reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242), using $\bmod \color{#90f}{k\!+\!2}\!:\ k\equiv -2\Rightarrow \color{#0a0}{k^2\!-\!1\equiv 3}$. Finally the gcd $\,(3,k\!+\!2)=3$ if $\,k\equiv 1\pmod{\!3},\,$ else the gcd $=1\ \ $

Comment: Re: proof in your prior comment: to remove the factor  $k+1$ from the first arg of the gcd we need it to be coprime to the 2nd arg, i.e. to both $k$ *and* $k+2,\,$ but you didn't mention such for $k+2$. Once you do so the proof is fine. We can also use gcd mod reduction instead of your second invocation of Euclid's Lemma, i.e. $(k-1,f(k)) = (k-1,f(1))$ for a polynomial $\,f(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$ (as in my prior comment).

Comment: Once all is clear its best to delete this question since we already have too many questions  on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have

- $A=k^2-1=(k+1)(k-1)$, and
- $B=(k+1)^2-1=k(k+2)$.

Thus:

- $A$ and $B$ cannot be simultaneously even;
- If $3$ divides $k-1$ then $3$ divides both $A$ and $B$;
- every prime $p>3$ can divide at most one of $4$ consecutive numbers, so $p$ cannot divide $A$ and $B$ at the same time.

Comment: Thanks Andrea, how did you come up with the following conclusion :- every prime >3
can divide at most one of 4 consecutive numbers  ?

Comment: @Fin27: it's obvious. If $p$ is a prime the only nonnegative integers divisible by $p$ are $0$, $p$, $2p$, $3p$ and so on. They are separated by intervals of length $p$.