# How much can a sum of fractions reduce?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fractions

Assume $x/a$ and $y/b$ are reduced, i.e. $\,\gcd(x,a) = 1 = \gcd(y,b)$.

$${\rm if}\ \ \dfrac{x}a+\dfrac{y}b=\dfrac{z}c\ \ {\rm does}\  \dfrac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)^2}\mid c\ ?\qquad$$

Comment: Actually, $\dfrac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)^2} \mid c \mid \dfrac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}$.

Comment: @lhf $\:$ Indeed $\rm\ c\:(a,b)\ |\ c\ (b\ x + a\ y) = zab\ \Rightarrow\  c\ | zab/(a,b)\ \Rightarrow\ c\ | ab/(a,b)\ $ by $\rm\ (c,z) = 1\:.$ $\quad\qquad$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, $\,\rm c\,$ must be divisible by $\,\rm \dfrac{ab}{(a,b)^2} = \dfrac{lcm(a,b)}{(a,b)}.\,$ Below are a few proofs.

$\rm(1)\ \ abz = bcx + acy\ \Rightarrow\ a,b\ |\ ac,bc\ \Rightarrow\ lcm(a,b)\ |\ (a,b)\ c\ \Rightarrow\ lcm(a,b)/(a,b)\ |\ c\ \ $ **QED**

Note $\rm\ lcm(a,b)/(a,b) =\: ab/(a,b)^2\ $ by the [LCM $\cdot$ GCD law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3149/242) $\rm\ lcm(a,b)\ (a,b)\ =\ a\:b\:.$

We used [lcm & gcd universal laws:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3356212/242) $\rm\ a,b\ |\ x,y \iff lcm(a,b)\ |\ x,y \iff lcm(a,b)\ |\ (x,y)\:. $

Below are two more proofs, the first a bit more conceptual and more detailed.

$(2)\ $ Suppose  $\rm\ c\ $ is a denominator for  $\rm\ \dfrac{x}a\: +\: \dfrac{y}b\ $ where $\rm\ (a,x) = 1 = (b,y)\:.\ $ Then we infer

$\rm\phantom{\quad\Rightarrow\quad}\: c\ \left(\dfrac{x}a\: +\: \dfrac{y}b\right) =\: z \in \mathbb Z\ \ \Rightarrow\ \  abz\ =\ cbx + cay\ \Rightarrow\ \ a\ |\ cbx,\ \ b\ |\ cay$

$\rm\quad\Rightarrow\quad c\ \left\{\dfrac{b}a,\ \dfrac{a}b\right\}\subset\: \mathbb Z\ \ $
by $\rm\   (a,x) = 1,\ \ a\ |\ cbx\ \Rightarrow\ a\ |\ cb\:.\ $ Similarly $\rm\ b\ |\ ca\:.$

$\rm\quad\Rightarrow\quad c\ \left\{\dfrac{\beta}\alpha,\ \dfrac{\alpha}\beta\right\}\subset\: \mathbb Z\ \ $ by cancelling out $\rm\ (a,b),\:$ with $\rm\ \alpha = a/(a,b),\ \ \beta = b/(a,b)\:.\ $

$\rm\quad\Rightarrow\quad c\ \left\{\dfrac{1}\alpha,\ \dfrac{1}\beta\right\}\subset\: \mathbb Z\ \ $  by $\rm\ (\alpha,\beta) = 1,\ \ \alpha\ |\ c\:\beta\ \Rightarrow\ \alpha\ |\ c\:.\ $ Similarly $\rm\ \beta\ |\ c\:. \ $

$\rm\quad\Rightarrow\quad  c\ \:\left(\dfrac{1}\alpha\ \:\dfrac{1}\beta\right)\  \in\  \mathbb Z\  $ by $\rm\: \alpha,\beta\ |\ c\ \Rightarrow\ lcm(\alpha,\beta)\ |\ c\:.\: $  $\rm lcm(\alpha,\beta) = \alpha\: \beta\ $ by $\rm\: (\alpha,\beta) = 1. $

$(3)\ $ Finally, here is another proof based upon squaring a gcd and applying basic gcd laws.

$\rm\ \ abz\ =\ bcx\: +\: acy\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ a\ |\ bcx\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ a\ |\ bc\ $ by $\rm\ (a,x) = 1\:.\ $ Similarly $\rm\ b\ |\ ac\:.$

$\rm Thus\quad \rm a\ |\ bc,\ b\ |\ ac\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ ab\ |\ a^2c,\ abc,\ b^2 c $

$\rm \phantom{Thus\quad \rm a\ |\ bc,\ b\ |\ ac\ \ } \Rightarrow\ \ ab\ |\ (a^2c,\ abc,\ b^2 c)\ =\ (a,b)^2\:c\quad\ $ **QED**

Note that the above proof uses only basic gcd laws (associative, commutative, distributive, etc) therefore it holds true in any GCD domain. Below is some further detail using said laws

$$\rm (a,b)\,(a,b)\,=\,(a(a,b),b(a,b))\,=\,((a^2,ab),(ab,b^2))\,=\,(a^2,ab,ab,b^2)\,=\,(a^2,ab,b^2) $$

For further discussion of arithmetic using such laws [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/62078/242)

**Remark** $\ $ Further $\rm\ c \mid \dfrac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}\ $ if $\,z/c\,$ is reduced, i.e. $\,\rm (c,z)=1,\,$ by $$\rm\ c\:(a,b)\mid  c\ (b x + a y) = zab\ \Rightarrow\  c \mid \dfrac{zab}{(a,b)}\ \Rightarrow\ c\mid \dfrac{ab}{(a,b)}\ \ {\rm by}\ \ (c,z)=1$$

Combining the above we obtain the following

**Theorem** $\ \ \rm (x,a)\!=\!(y,b)\!=\!(z,x)\!=\!1,\ \ \dfrac{x}a+\dfrac{y}b = \dfrac{z}c\ \Rightarrow\ \dfrac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)^2}\, {\Large \mid }\ c\ {\Large\mid}\ \dfrac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4486800/242) for a formula for teh denominator $\,c\,$  of the reduced sum $\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is true. To see this, let $g = \gcd(a,b)$ so we can rewrite the sum as
$$ \dfrac x {ga} + \dfrac y { gb} = \dfrac z c $$
where $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(a,x) = \gcd(b,y) = 1$. Then
$$ \dfrac{ bx + ay } {gab} = \dfrac z c. $$
But $\gcd(a,bx) = 1$ so the factor of $a$ cannot cancel, and similarly neither can the factor of $b$. Thus
$$ ab = \dfrac{ ga \cdot gb }{g^2} | c $$
as desired.

Comment: You re-defined $a$ and $b$! So I have to keep track in my mind of which $a$'s and $b$'s are the original ones, and which are your re-defined ones. That's terrible! Call them $e$ and $f$. Please.

Comment: @TonyK, $a'$ and $b'$ are pretty usual for that role.

Comment: @lhf: As long as it's not $a$ and $b$.