# if n is a positive integer let Z be the subset of integer in {1,...,n} which are relatively prime to n

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, terminology

if n is a positive integer let Z be the subset of integer in {1,...,n} which are relatively prime to n

[image]

my effort to solve this question [image]

I''m confused and need help to solve this question please

Comment: Your current "solution" doesn't seem to be on the right track. Start with the assumption that $a,b$ are relatively prime to $n$. In GCD notation this is $(a,n)=(b,n)=1$. You're required to show that $(ab,n)=1$ which will imply the result. As a hint, you could write the prime factorization of $a,b$ and $n$

Answer (score 1):

The elements of $\mathbf Z_n^\times$ are the integers in $\{1,\dots,n\}$ which have an inverse modulo $n$ (thanks to *Bézout's theorem*).

Now if $aa'\equiv 1\mod n$ and $bb'\mod n$, then $(ab)(a'b')=(aa')(bb')\equiv1\mod n$, hence $ab$ has an inverse modulo $n$.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to show that if $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$, i.e.,
if $gcd(a,n)=gcd(b,n)=1$, then also $gcd(ab,n)=1$, and hence $ab\in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$. You can find the proof several times here on this site, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586480/if-gcda-n-1-and-gcdb-n-1-then-gcdab-n-1), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62072/how-to-show-that-gcdab-n-1).