# $n$-ary Congruence Product Rule (in proof of Euler's totient theorem)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

Fermat's theorem: if a is not divisible by p, then $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$

Since $\varphi(p)=p-1$, this is a special case of Euler's theorem. If $(a,m)=1$, then $a^{\varphi(m)}\equiv 1 \pmod m$.

Proof: Let $c_1,.....,c_{\varphi(m)}$ be a reduced residue system $(mod\text{ } m)$ and let a be prime to m. Then $ac_1,.....,ac_{\varphi(m)}$ is also a reduced residue system $(mod\text{ } m)$, and therefore

$$\prod_{i=1}^{\varphi(m)}ac_i \equiv \prod_{i=1}^{\varphi(m)}c_i \pmod m$$

Why is the latter true?

$\varphi(p)$ counts the number of elements ina reduced residue system mod p

Comment: m is a prime number

Comment: There is only one reduce residue system mod $m$. We have $\{c_1,\ldots,c_{\varphi(m)}\}=\{ac_1,\ldots,ac_{\phi(m)}\}$, i.e. $c_1,\ldots,c_{\varphi(m)}$ is a permutation of $ac_1,\ldots,ac_{\phi(m)}$. Therefore, we have $c_1\cdots c_{\varphi(m)}\equiv ac_1\cdots ac_{\phi(m)}\pmod{m}$. By the way, e.g. we also have $c_1+\cdots+c_{\varphi(m)}\equiv ac_1+\cdots+ac_{\varphi(m)}\pmod{m}$, which is irrelevant here.

Comment: Sorry, but your Question was unclear.  Apparently you are asking why a proof of Euler's theorem works?

Comment: Or maybe you're asking why $ac_1,\ldots,ac_{\phi(m)}$ is also a reduced residue system mod $m$?

Comment: I am just typing what the book says,  but my question is why the latter works. Why can you say such statement?

Comment: @TheMathNoob Which statement exactly?

Comment: $\prod_{i=1}^{\varphi(m)}ac_i \equiv \prod_{i=1}^{\varphi(m)}c_i \text{ }(mod \text{ }m)$

Comment: @TheMathNoob I explained it in my other comment.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much

Comment: Right, so there is a bijection between the two residue systems and each element is the same, so their product is the same which implies that $\prod_{i=1}^{\varphi(m)}ac_i -\prod_{i=1}^{\varphi(m)}c_i =0$ Right?

Comment: @TheMathNoob There exists exactly one reduced residue system mod $m$, so if you prove that $c_1,\ldots,c_{\varphi(m)}$ and $ac_1,\ldots,ac_{\varphi(m)}$ are both reduced residue systems mod $m$, then you know that for each $i\in\{1,\ldots,\varphi(m)\}$ there exists exactly one $j\in\{1,\ldots,\varphi(m)\}$ such that $c_i=ac_j$ (and vice versa, i.e. for each $j$ exists exactly one $i$). I.e., $\{c_1,\ldots,c_{\varphi(m)}\}=\{ac_1,\ldots,ac_{\varphi(m)}\}$, or i.e. $c_1,\ldots,c_{\varphi(m)}$ is a permutation of $ac_1,\ldots,ac_{\varphi(m)}$.

Comment: @TheMathNoob $c_1,\ldots,c_{\varphi(m)}$ and $ac_1,\ldots,ac_{\varphi(m)}$ are both the same reduced residue system, just perhaps ordered differently.

Comment: Each $c_i $ is congruent to some other $ac_j $.  So any $xc_i=xac_j mod p $ for any x.  So the product of all of the residues are congruent to the other equivalent residue system.

Comment: Yes I got, but the difference has to be zero hence it's the same set

Answer (score 1):

The sets
$$ \{c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_{\varphi(m)}\},\qquad \{ac_1,ac_2,\ldots,ac_{\varphi(m)}\} $$
are the same set $\!\!\pmod{m}$, hence the product of the elements has to be the same:
$$ a^{\varphi(m)}\prod_{k=1}^{\varphi(m)}c_k \equiv \prod_{k=1}^{\varphi(m)}c_k\pmod{m} $$
leads to $a^{\varphi(m)}\equiv 1\pmod{m}$ as wanted.

Comment: Explain the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

An important part here is that for $(a,m)=1$ you have
$$ab\equiv ac \pmod m \Rightarrow b\equiv c \pmod m.$$
This implies that $\{ac_1,\dots,ac_{\varphi(m)}\}$ belong to $\varphi(m)$ *different* residue classes.

Moreover, if $(a,m)=1$ and $(c,m)=1$, then also $(ac,m)=1$. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288561/prove-that-if-gcda-c-1-and-gcdb-c-1-then-gcdab-c-1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586480/if-gcda-n-1-and-gcdb-n-1-then-gcdab-n-1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673119/if-gcd-a-b-1-and-gcd-a-c-1-then-gcd-a-bc-1).) So all of them are reduced residue classes.

Therefore $\{ac_1,\dots,ac_{\varphi(m)}\}$ is a reduced residue system. (It has $\varphi(m)$ elements, each number is in a different residue class, each number is coprime to $m$.)

Answer (score 0):

Recall the [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $ $   [below all congruences are $ $ mod $\,m$]

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
&&\quad  b_1\!\!&\equiv&\, c_1\\
&&\quad b_2\!\!&\equiv&\, c_2\\
\Rightarrow\  &&b_1 b_2\!\! &\equiv&\, c_1 c_2
\end{eqnarray}$$

By induction the rule extends to $\ b_i\equiv c_i\,\Rightarrow\, \prod  b_i \equiv \prod  c_i$

In other words, if two equal length lists $\,B,C\,$  of integers are element-wise congruent $\,b_i \equiv c_i\,$ then their products are also congruent. Yours is the special case where $\, B = \{b_i\},\ C = \{c_i\}\,$ are reduced residue systems.

Alternatively it is a special case of the multivariate extension of the  [Congruence Polynomial Rule,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) for the $\,k$-ary product  polynomial $\,P(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_k) = x_1 x_2\cdots x_k,\ $ i.e.

$$ b_i\equiv c_i\,\Rightarrow\, P(b_1,b_2,\ldots, b_k) \equiv P(c_1, c_2,\ldots, c_k)$$