# If $(a,b) = 1$, then $(n, ab) = 1 \iff (n,a) = 1 = (n,b)$. How to prove it?

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I'm having some trouble proving the question above, most because i'm getting a proof that works even if $(a,b) \neq 1$ and i just can't find my mistake.

**Proof:** if $(n, ab) = 1$, $\exists x$, $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x\cdot n + y\cdot ab = 1$, but this means that $x\cdot n + ya \cdot b = 1$ and $x\cdot n + yb\cdot a = 1$ and so $(n,a) = 1$ and $(n,b) = 1$. Now, if $(n,a) = 1 = (n,b)$, $\exists x'$, $x''$, $y'$, $y'' \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x'\cdot n + y'\cdot a = 1$ and $x''\cdot n + y''\cdot b = 1 \Rightarrow x'\cdot x''\cdot n^2 + x'\cdot y''\cdot n\cdot b + x''\cdot y'\cdot n\cdot a + y'\cdot y''\cdot a\cdot b = 1 \Rightarrow n\cdot (x'x''n + x'y''b + x''y'a) + y'y''\cdot ab = 1 \Rightarrow (n,ab) = 1$

Note that i did not request that (a,b) = 1 at any time.

Comment: The condition that $(a,b)=1$ is redundant.

Comment: I would use the criterion that $(n,a)=1$ iff $a$ is a unit in $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$.

Comment: My suggestion is a contradiction proof : You assume that there is a prime $p$ dividing $n$ and $ab$ in one direction and dividing $n$ and $a$ or dividing $n$ and $b$ in the other.

Comment: What you are doing is fine. Ad you are right, the condition $(a,b)=1$ is not necessary. One way to see this is that $(n,ab)=1$ and $(n,a)=(n,b)=1$ both mean that $n$ and $ab$ have no primes in common.

Comment: [More conceptually](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/62078/242) $\bmod n\!:\ (ab)^{-1}\,$ exists $\iff a^{-1},b^{-1}\,$ exist, i.e. units (invertibles) are closed under product and divisors, i.e. they form a saturated monoid.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate proof for the second part $$\gcd(n,a) = 1 \implies \gcd(n,ab) = \gcd(n,b)$$

$\begin{align}\gcd(n,ab)&=\gcd(\gcd(n,nb),ab)\\&=\gcd(n,ab,nb)\\
&=\gcd(n,\gcd(ab,nb))\\&=\gcd(n,b\gcd(a,n))\\
&=\gcd(n,b\times 1)\\&=\gcd(n,b)\\&=1\end{align}$