# If $[a],[b] \in \mathbb{Z}_n^* $ then $[ab] \in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$: a doubt about equivalence classes.

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations

If $n$ is a positive number, let $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ be the subset of class representatives in $\{1,..., n-1\}$ which are relatively prime to $n$. Show that if $[a],[b] \in \mathbb{Z}_n^* $ then $[ab] \in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$.

I think $[a]$ is an equivalence class. But what does it represent?
If $a = 1$, what does $[1]$ imply?

Update: this is what I understand so far.
For example, let n = 5, a = 2. Then relatively primes of n is {1,2,3,4}, and [a] = {2,4} because it's only 2 in {1,2,3,4} that has residual when divided by n = 5.
Is this correct?

Update: My thought on proving the problem.
Let [a] = {a + k*n | k $\in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$},  [b] = {b + l*n | l $\in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$}.
Pick an a' from [a] and b' from [b]. I can say a' = a + k*n, b' = b +l*n.
Then a'*b' = ab + n(ak + bk + $nk^2$). This is congruent to ab mod n.
Therefore [ab] $\in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$.
Would this be an appropriate proof?

Comment: It is an equivalence class on $\mathbb{Z}$: integers $a,b$ are equivalent if $a-b$ is divisible by $n$. Now, $\mathbb{Z_n}^*$ is the collection of the equivalence classes $[a]$ where $a$ is relatively prime to $n$. (this does not depend on the choice of the representatives)

Comment: so if a =1, then [a] = {1} ? sorry. I still don't get it. Can you give me an example, please

Comment: um.  "integers a,b are equivalent if a−b is divisible by n" 
is this line true by default? I thought the meaning of equivalency depends on how we define it.

Comment: The equivalence relation here depends on $n$. It is not “true by default” but “true by the meaning of what your notation means”. What do *you* think the notation $[a]$ used in your question is supposed to mean? Have you ever worked with some actual *examples* of elements of $\mathbf Z_n^*$?

Comment: I thought  Zn* is just a symbol.  Does it have its own meaning? 
I think [a] as I wrote in my question. I updated it.

Comment: For example, if $n=2$ then $[1]=\{...,-5,-3,-1,1,3,5,7,9,11,...\}$. In this case $[1]$ is  the set of all odd numbers.

Comment: The question is ill posed: it first defined $\mathbb Z_n^*$ as a set of *representatives*, so the elements are integers. Then it states “$[a]\in \mathbb Z_n^*$” implying that the elements of $\mathbb Z_n^*$ are now equivalence classes. Which one is it?

Comment: Semantics aside... this is just asking you to show that if $a$ is relatively prime to $n$ and $b$ is also relatively prime to $n$ then $a\times b$ is also relatively prime to $n$.  Further, if any number $A$ has the same remainder as $a$ when divided by $n$ and any number $B$ has the same remainder as $b$ when divided by $n$ then $A\times B$ has the same remainder as $a\times b$ when divided by $n$.

Comment: You are getting bogged down by notation which wasn't supposed to be the challenge of this problem but still a necessary thing to get used to.  With $n=5$, what was intended was for $[2]$ to represent the set of all integers who have remainder $2$ when divided by $n$ which happens to be $[2]=\{\dots,-8,-3,2,7,12,\dots\}$.  Now... when $n$ happened to be prime you'll have $1,2,\dots,n-1$ are all coprime to $n$ and this is a particularly important example you'll revisit later.  More importantly for now however is when $n$ is not prime, we'll be skipping some of those numbers yet it remains closed

Comment: In regards to your update, you have shown that $[a]\cdot [b]$ is well defined, but you haven't yet shown that $[ab]\in\Bbb Z_n^*$ specifically, only that $[ab]\in\Bbb Z_n$.  You still need to show that $ab$ is coprime to $n$ so long as $a$ and $b$ are coprime to $n$.

Comment: The titled inference is a frequent DUPE, e.g. see [How to show $a,b$ coprime to $n\Rightarrow ab$ coprime to $n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/62072/242)

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb{Z}$, we define an equivalence relation by :
$$ a \text{ and } b \text{ are equivalent } \iff n \mid b-a  $$
so  $[a]=\{ b\in \mathbb{Z} : a \text{ and } b \text{ are equivalent }\}=\{ b \in \mathbb{Z}  : n|b-a\}=\{ b\in \mathbb{Z} : b-a=nk \text{ s.t } k\in \mathbb{Z}\}=\{a+nk : k\in \mathbb{Z}\},$

Thus  in $\mathbb{Z}_3$,  for example $[1]=\{1+3k : k\in \mathbb{Z}\}=\{\cdots,-2,1,4,7,\cdots \}.$

Comment: I have edited my answer. Thank you @halrankard2.

Comment: Looks good. You might add explicitly that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is defined to be the set of equivalence classes. That would help in reconciling the example with $n=3$.