# How to use fundamental theorem of arithmetic to conclude that $\gcd(a^k,b^n)=1$ for all $k, n \in$ N whenever $a,b \in$ N with $\gcd(a,b)=1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, prime-factorization

How to use fundamental theorem of arithmetic to conclude that $\gcd(a^k,b^n)=1$ for all $k, n \in$ **N** whenever $a,b \in$ **N** with $\gcd(a,b)=1$?

[Fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic): Each number $n\geq 2$ can be presented in an unique way as a product
$n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2} \dots p_r^{a_r}$, where
$p_i$ are primes $p_1<p_2< \dots <p_r$ and $a_i \in$ **N**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint:**  $\gcd(a,b)=1$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ share no prime factors.

Comment: But doesn't it mean that if gcd(a,b)=1 then a and b are primes. How then they have prime factorization?

Comment: @alvoutila: $\gcd(a,b)=1$ does _not_ mean that $a$ and $b$ are primes.  Instead, $\gcd(a,b)=1$ means that if $d>0$ divides both $a$ and $b$, then $d$ must be $1$.  Example:  $\gcd(24,35)=1$, but neither are primes.

Answer (score 10):

**Hint** $\rm\ $ prime $\rm\ p\: |\: n^k\ \Rightarrow\ p\: |\: n\ $ by *uniqueness* of prime factorizations.

**Note** $\ $ In fact *uniqueness* of factorizations into primes (i.e. atoms) is equivalent to the following

**Prime Divisor Property**  $\rm\quad p\ |\ a\:b\ \Rightarrow\ p\:|\:a\ $ or $\rm\ p\:|\:b,\ $ for all primes $\rm\:p\,;\:\: $ more generally

**Primal Divisor Property**  $\rm\ \ \: c\ |\ a\:b\ \Rightarrow\ c_1\, |\: a\:,\: $ $\rm\ c_2\:|\:b,\ \ c = c_1\:c_2,\ $ for all $\rm\:c$

The latter property may be considered to be a generalization of the prime divisor property from atoms to composites (one easily checks that atoms are  primal $\Leftrightarrow$ prime). This leads to various "refinement" views of unique factorizations, e.g. via [Schreier refinement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6653/basic-divisibility-fact/6657#6657) and [Riesz interpolation,](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~hb3/publ/euk-2.pdf) the Euclid-Euler [Four Number Theorem](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~hb3/publ/euk-1.pdf) (Vierzahlensatz), etc, which prove more natural in noncommutative rings - see  Paul Cohn's 1973 Monthly survey [Unique Factorization Domains.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2319253)

Comment: can you please tell me what the "|" means?

Comment: @paulpaul1076 It means "divides" (standard number theory notation)

Comment: thanks, I have only seen the three dots notation for that.

Comment: @paulpaul1076 That's relatively rare. The above notation is by far the most widely used.

Answer (score 5):

The prime factors of $a^k$ are exactly the same as the prime factors of $a$.
Hence, a prime $p$ divides both $a^k$ and $b^n$ iff it divides both $a$ and $b$. Furthermore, $\gcd(a,b)=1$ iff $a$ and $b$ share no prime factors. Thus $\gcd(a^k,b^n)=1$ iff $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Comment: do you mean that if $a= p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2} \dots p_r^{a_r}$ then $a^k =p_1^{ka_1}p_2^{ka_2} \dots p_r^{ka_r}$ But then how conclude from here that $gcd(a^k, a^n)=1$? And besides that if gcd(a,b)=1 then a and b are primes so how you get prime factorization for these numbers not to mention to $a^k$?

Comment: @alvoutila, I've edited my answer to give a complete solution, incorporating Eric's hint.

Comment: I still am uncertain because I thought that is gcd(a,b)=1 it would mean that a and b are primes? Is this true? But if it is true that gcd(a,b)=1 => 1|a and 1|b, then it might mean that they are primes. So how is it possible to say that they don't prime factors, when there are no factors, because they are already primes?

Comment: @alvoutila, $\gcd(a,b)=1$ means that $a$ and $b$ are *coprime*, that is, they have no prime factors in common. It does *not* mean that $a$ and $b$ are prime. For instance $12$ and $35$ are coprime but neither is prime.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is to first prove that $(a,b) = 1$ and $(a,c) =1$ implies $(a, bc)=1$. Your problem then follows by induction.

To prove the lemma, notice that $ax + by = 1$ and $az + cw = 1$ imply

$$ax + by(az+cw) = 1$$
$$ax + byaz + (bc)yw = 1$$
$$a(x+byz) + bc (yw) = 1.$$