# Multiplicative monoid of a commutative ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Is there any good description of the multiplicative monoid of a commutative ring in general? Or in special cases?

I understand that in a UFD, it is the result of adjoining a zero to the Cartesian product of the unit group with a free commutative monoid, but that's pretty much the only case I understand. :(

Comment: How about the case of a Dedekind domain? You should be able to describe the multiplicative monoid in terms of the unit group and the class group, I think.

Comment: I've been having trouble wrapping my head around it -- it doesn't seem like it gives you  any information about the relationships between cancellation monoids $R^*$, $R \setminus \{ 0 \}$, and the free monoid on the prime ideals beyond what's contained in the groups they generate.

Answer (score 8):

Many properties of domains are purely multiplicative so can be described in terms of monoid structure. Let R be a domain with fraction field K. Let R* and K* be the
multiplicative groups of units of R and K respectively. Then
G(R), the *divisibility group* of R, is the factor group K*/R*.

- R is a UFD $\iff$ G(R) is a sum of copies of $\rm\:\mathbb Z\:.$
- R is a gcd-domain $\iff$ G(R) is lattice-ordered (lub{x,y} exists)
- R is a valuation domain $\iff$ G(R) is linearly ordered
- R is a Riesz domain $\iff$ G(R) is a Riesz group, i.e.
  an ordered group satisfying the Riesz interpolation property: if  $\rm\:a,b \le c,d\:$  then  $\rm\:a,b \le x \le c,d\:$  for some $\rm\:x\:.\:$ A domain $\rm\:R\:$ is called Riesz if every element is [primal,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63323/how-to-use-fundamental-theorem-of-arithmetic-to-conclude-that-gcdak-bn-1-f/63330#63330) i.e. $\rm\:A\:|\:BC\ \Rightarrow\ A = bc,\ b|B,\ c|C\:,\:$ for some $\rm\:b,c\in R\:.$

---

[image]
[image]

For more on divisibility groups see the following surveys:

J.L. Mott, Groups of divisibility: A unifying concept for
integral domains and partially ordered groups, Mathematics
and its Applications, no. 48, 1989, pp. 80-104.

J.L. Mott, The group of divisibility and its applications,
Conference on Commutative Algebra (Univ. Kansas, Lawrence, Kan.,
1972), Springer, Berlin, 1973, pp. 194-208. Lecture Notes in Math.,
Vol. 311. MR 49 #2712

Comment: While this is interesting, I was wondering specifically about the monoid structure -- e.g. can we say much about the submonoid of $G(R)$ generated by the nonzero elements of $R$?

Comment: I think you asked this question when I had lost interest, you should read Franz Halter-Koch's book entitled "Ideals Systems: An introduction to Multiplicative Ideal Theory".

Comment: The monoid of elements of an integral domain is cancellative i.e. if a is nonzero, then ab=ac implies b=c. Using this as a starting point Halter-Koch studied and translated most of the then known notions in multiplicative ideal theory into the language of ideal systems on monoids. It was a good addition to the literature, though his insistence that monoids were the only way to do ring theory drew resistance from some quarters.

Comment: @mzafrullah Yes. I mentioned Halter=Koch's work briefly in passing  [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/178825/242). Nice to see you back here.

Comment: Consider it a brief appearance to say "Happy Thanksgiving y'all". About Halter-Koch, he apparently translated everything that was known except for Schreier domains and that seemed a little odd to me. So I have put together something on Riesz monoids to remedy that. (Still working on fine-tuning it.)

Comment: @BillDubuque: Regarding the first bullet point, about UFDs: won't G(R), as an abstract group, be a sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ for any Dedekind domain, for instance? Perhaps the statement holds once you introduce an appropriate partial order though?

Comment: @ndkrempel  I appended an excerpt which gives more detail (too long for a comment).

Answer (score 3):

"Riesz domains" have been studied extensively as pre-Schreier and Schreier domains, and Bill Dubuque should have known that! In any case, here's a link that might be useful:
http://www.lohar.com/researchpdf/on_a_property_of_pre_schreier_domains.pdf

The paper and the references therein will be helpful for the monoid question too.
There have been quite a few generalizations of the pre-Schreier domains too and references to some of them could show up at places on the page www.lohar.com

Comment: In fact I do strive to  spread the Schreier gospel here - having mentioned it and  related divisibility properties [many times](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=schreier%20user%3a242) here since the dawn of the site, including links to your work (I discovered your answer only just now after your comment on mine).