# Prove $ 2^{7}\cdot3^{7} \notin \{72, 108\}^{*} $

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic

I Want to prove $ 2^{7}\cdot3^{7} \notin \{72, 108\}^{*} $, where $A^* = \{72^n \cdot 108^m \mid n,m \in \mathbb(Z)_0 \land m+n > 0\}$. Can you please verify my proof?

Proof:

Let $ A = \{72, 108\} $ and assme $ 2^7\cdot3^7 \in A^*$. Therefore, there exist $ n, m \in \mathbb{N}_0, m + n \gt 0$, such that $ 2^7\cdot3^7 = 72^m\cdot108^n $.

The prime factorization of $ 72 $ is $ 2^3\cdot3^2 $ and the prime factorization of $ 108 $ is $ 2^2\cdot3^3 $.

Therefore, $ (2^2\cdot3^3)^n\cdot(3^2\cdot2^3)^m = 2^7\cdot3^7 $, which is the same as saying $ 3^{3n+2m}\cdot2^{3m + 2n} = 2^7\cdot3^7 $.

According to the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, each composite number has a single and unique prime factorization. Hence:

$$ 3m + 2n = 7 $$
$$ 2m + 3n = 7 $$

We'll solve the system of equations.

$$ 3m + 2n = 7 \Rightarrow 2n = 7 - 3m \Rightarrow n = \frac{7 - 3m}{2} $$

Thus:

$$ 3n + 2m = 7 \Rightarrow 3[\frac{1}{2}(7 - 3m)] + 2m = 7 \Rightarrow 3(7 - 3m) + 4m = 14 \Rightarrow 21 - 9m + 4m = 14 \Rightarrow 21 - 5m = 14 \Rightarrow 5m = 7 \Rightarrow m = \frac{5}{7} \notin \mathbb{N}_0 $$

And that is a contradiction.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\{72, 108\}^{*}
$?

Comment: $ \{72^n\cdot108^m | n, m \in \mathbb{N}_0 \land m + n \gt 0\} $

Comment: Please enclose any of your definitions you use (no matter how exotic) in the body of your question, so people may know what you are talking about. Thank you!

Comment: I performed the same analysis as you did.  So, either your analysis is right, or I made the same mistake that you did.

Comment: Woosh!  You *really* should not assume anyone outside you class has any idea what $\{72,108\}*$.  And you really should respond to wasn't me's request, and edit your question to include the definition of $\{72, 108\}*$ in your question.

Comment: @fleablood Jeez, just thought is was something universal

Comment: I expanded my answer to show how similar methods can be used to prove irrationality of square roots. If anything is unclear then let me know and I can elaborate,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly simpler version of your proof in the same vein. As noted, $72 = 2^33^2$ and $108 = 2^23^3$

Assume there exist integral $m, n$ such that $3m + 2n = 7$ and $2m + 3n = 7$. Then $5m + 5n = 14$ (by adding the two). Since $5$ does not divide $ 14$, a contradiction is reached. No such $m, n$ therefore exist.

Comment: Thank you, but I wrote this proof on a test today and I want to lnow if it's true

Comment: @ItayHagadi Any method that arrives at the result through a contradiction on the assumption that $m,n$ are integral is correct. That includes yours.

Comment: $ 3m+2n=7=2n+3m$ implies $0=7-7=(3m+2n)-(2m+3n)=m-n$ implies $m=n.$ But then $7=3m+2n=5m.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Note that it is quicker to simply compare the *lengths* of the prime factorization - as I explain in my answer. This avoids having to deal with a *system* of equations, and leads *immediately* to the sought modular contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is fine. It simplifies - to solve the equations simply add them, which immediately yields the modular contradiction: $\,\color{#c00}5$ divides $\color{#0a0}{14} \color{#c00}\Rightarrow\!\color{#0a0}\Leftarrow\:\!$. Quicker and simpler:  compare the prime factorization *lengths* (#primes) on both sides of  $\,72^{\rm N} 108^{\rm M} =2^7 3^7$ as below:

$$\begin{align}\text{ Suppose that}\ \ \overbrace{(2^{\large\color{#c00}3} 3^{\large\color{#c00}2})^{\rm N}(2^{\large\color{#c00}2} 3^{\large\color{#c00}3})^{\rm  M}}^{\textstyle 72^{\rm N} \  108^{\rm M}\!\!\!\!}\! &\,=\, 2^{\large\color{#0a0}7} 3^{\large\color{#0a0}7}\\[.2em] 
\text{$\color{#90f}{\rm count}$ #primes}\:\Rightarrow\: {\color{#c00}5\:\!{\rm\small N}\ \:\!+\:\!\ {\color{#c00}5\:\!{\rm\small M}}} &\,=\, \color{#0a0}{14}\ \color{#c00}\Rightarrow\!\color{#0a0}\Leftarrow\end{align}\qquad$$

---

**Generalization** $ $ Define $\,\color{#90f}{\ell(n)}\,$ as the  $\rm\color{#90f}{count}$ of all primes (length) in the unique prime factorization of $\:\!n.\,$ The above generalizes to:  $\,\gcd(\ell(a),\ell(b))\mid \ell(a^n b^m)\ [= n\:\!\ell(a)+m\:\!\ell(b)].\,$ The question is the special case when $\, \ell(a) = \ell(b)\ [= 5]\, $ thus $\,\ell(a)\mid \ell(a^nb^m).\,$

---

**Remark** $ $ Note this "global" method of counting the total number of primes ends up being simpler than the "local" methods of comparing the powers of each prime (e.g. using valuations $\,\nu_p).\,$ While generally the local methods can discriminate better, this extra work may not be needed to handle simple problems like this.

E.g. the global method  quickly proves irrational square roots of *odd* length $n\,$ (e.g. prime $n)\,$ by $\,\sqrt n =a/b \Rightarrow nb^2 = a^2\,$ contra parity: $\,\ell(a^2)$ is even but $\,\ell(nb^2)\,$ is odd by $\,\ell(n)\,$ odd. But this method doesn't handle even length $\,n,\,$ so we need to resort to local methods to handle e.g. $\sqrt 6,\,$ e.g. by comparing the parity of the length (power) of $2$ on both sides (i.e. apply valuation $\nu_2)$.

This length "metric" $\,\ell(n)\,$ often proves handy, e.g. it can be used as a metric for descent in certain generalizations of the Euclidean algorithm to arbitrary PIDs, see the [Dedekind Hasse PID test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/221700/242).

Notice that the proof uses only *length* uniqueness of prime factorizations. Domains satisfying this "half" of the common definition of unique prime factorization are known as *half-factorial domains*. A classical result of Carlitz shows that a number ring is half-factorial iff it has class number $\le 2.\,$ Recent work generalizes this, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/178825/242). One interesting simple result is: if a domain is not a UFD then that is witnessed by the existence of an *equal-length* nonunique factorization, see Coykendall and Smith, [Unique factorization domains.](http://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/%7Ecoykenda/paper37b.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

Once you figured out the particular form of the factorization of $72$ and $108$, there is a way to speedrun your exam.

In fact since $2^7\cdot 3^7$ involves very small exponents you can take advantage of this to enumerate the only $3$ possibilities that arise rather than going for a general arithmetic proof and save a lot of time to answer the other questions in the test.

$\begin{align}2^7\cdot 3^7&=54\times 72^2\\&=36\times 72\times 108\\&=24\times 108^2\end{align}$

Since all remainders $54,36,24$ are too small to constitute another factor of $\{72,108\}$ then we can safely conclude that such a factorization is not possible.

Comment: I think the OP wants to rule out *negative* exponents for either of $72$,$108$ as well, and this does make it trickier.