# Cancellative Abelian Monoids II

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid, least-common-multiple, gcd-and-lcm

Following [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266059/cancellative-abelian-monoids) question I was asking myself if (in a cancellative Abelian Monoid $M$) given three elements $a,\, b,\, c$ for which there exists the least common multiple $m$, it will also exists the greatest common divisor.

Is it maybe possible to find a Cancellative Abelian monoid in which there are three elements with a lcm but without a gcd?

Comment: Note that (think of the naturals) for three elements $a,b,c \in M$ we cannot hope that from $abc = dm$, $d$ is the greatest common divisor, instead we want something like $abc = d^2m$.

Comment: I see. Do you think some result could be obtained? I will change the question.