# Quotient set of associate elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, reference-request, equivalence-relations, quotient-set

Let $R$ be a ring with $1$. We say that $a,b\in R$ are *associate* if $a|b$ and $b|a$, i.e. there exist $r,s\in R$ such that $a=rb$ and $b=sa$. This is an equivalence relation on $R$, and I would like to know if the quotient set $R/\sim$ (where $a\sim b$ when $a$ and $b$ are associate) has interesting properties such that a given structure or information about $R$.

In particular, I'm interested in the case where $R$ is an integral domain, where $a\sim b$ if and only if $r$ and $s$ above are units. If further the units of $R$ commute with every element, then $R/\sim$ inherits a monoid structure from $R$, since $ua\cdot vb=uvab$, and therefore the product in $R$ induces a well defined product in the quotient. However, the sum in $R$ isn't preserved in general in $R/\sim$.

Some examples I've played with without getting much more information are $\mathbb{Z}$ (where the monoid is just $\mathbb{N}$), fields (monoid $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$), several instances of $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$ (I know these are not in general integral domains, but I wanted to know how they look like) and some polynomial rings.

To sum up, my question is

> Has this quotient set been studied for some family of rings and has any interesing properties?

Comment: Isn't this quotient set the basis for discussing unique factorization in commutative domains?  I'd say that qualifies as "some family of rings" it has been studied for...  In that context, I think it's isomorphic to the poset of principal ideals of the ring.  In a more general context, I'm not sure what survives.

Comment: @rschwieb oh yes! You're absolutely right. I didn't thought it that way, thanks.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66572/242) on *divisibility groups*.

Comment: @BillDubuque thank you

Comment: For more recent work e.g. see [Divisibility theory of commutative rings and ideal distributivity, P. N. Anh, Keith A. Kearnes, Agnes Szendrei](http://math.uni.lu/aaa85/pdf/anh-pham-ngoc.pdf)