# Conflict in the definition of divisibility and definition of prime numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

I couldn't find this question with google, so maybe someone can help here :)

When looking at the definition of divisibility on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor), it is written that $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ $a \mid b \iff \exists c \in \mathbb{Z}: b = a \cdot c$

Following this, negative integers should also be a divisor. 
But, one definition of prime numbers states:

$p$ is prime $\iff$ p can only be divided by 1 and p

So every prime number $p$ should also be divided by $-p$ hence the defintion of divisibility, but this is not the case?

What am I missing out?

EDIT: I know there exists other definitions where this isnt an issue, but this definition is used and seems to be correct but still is in conflict with other definitions...In other words, is there a reason to use $\mathbb{Z}$ and not $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: It's just a matter of definition. If you use the definition you mentioned in $\mathbb N$ (not in $\mathbb Z$), you don't miss anything out.

Comment: We only consider the positive divisors. [Read this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeNumber.html) for definition of Prime Number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You omitted the $\color{#c00}{\rm context\!\!:}\ a\mid b\ \ \color{#c00}{{\rm in}\  M}\iff \exists\, c\ \ \color{#c00}{{\rm in}\ M\!:}\,  ac = b.\ $

In your case $\,\color{#c00}{M = \Bbb N}\,$ but generally in divisibility theory it can be any (cancellative) [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid). In fact many well-known properties of domains (e.g. UFD,GCD,valuation) can be described purely in terms of their multiplicative monoid - see [divisibility groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66572/242).