# Divisibility in complex numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, divisibility

I'm wondering if the concept of "divisibility" also works in complex numbers.

For example, if I say $a+bi$ is divisible by $c+di$. Does this mean that there exists another complex number $\alpha+\beta i$ such that $$\begin{align*}
(c+di)(\alpha+\beta i)=a+bi
\end{align*}$$If this is true, can I say that $5i$ is divisible by $5$ and is divisible by $i$ since $$\begin{align*}
5i=(5+0i)(0+i)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: This could make sense if we assume that all numbers appearing are integers , otherwise there is always such a complex number unless $c+di=0$

Comment: The definition of divisibility clearly  [works in any monoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3576252/242), and many divisibility properties are purely multiplicative and can be studied at the monoid level.

Comment: For $~0 + i(0) \neq z = x + iy, ~x,y \in \Bbb{R},~$ let $~\overline{z}~$ denote $~x - iy,~$ and let $~|z|~$ denote $~\displaystyle \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.~$  Then, at first glance, your divisibility question becomes trivial because, given any $~w \in \Bbb{C},~$ you have that $$\frac{w}{z} = \frac{w \times \overline{z}}{|z|^2} \implies w = \frac{w \times \overline{z}}{|z|^2} \times z.$$

Comment: The method in the prior comment (viewable similarly to rationalizing the denominator) works for division by any algebraic number - as explained at lenght [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/100201/242).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You certainly can do this. You can do this in any situation where multiplication makes sense -- although you have to watch out that in other settings, divisibility might not work the way you're used to.

If you use this definition for *all* complex numbers, you get something very boring: every complex number $z$ is divisible by every non-zero complex number $a$ because
$$
z = \frac za \times a.
$$
(You get something equally boring if you use all real numbers.)

However, if you limit yourself to complex numbers $a + bi$ where $a, b$ are integers, you get the [Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer), and there divisiblity is certainly interesting.

Comment: Gaussian integers are fun.  When I first saw them, I noticed that $10 = (3 + i)(3 - i)$ and I thought "factorization is not unique".  Actually it is (in a sense) but $2$ is not prime in this context as $2 = (1 + i)(1 - i)$.  Similarly, $5$, $3 + i$, and $3 - i$ are not prime either.

Comment: related: [this answer to *determining if a coincident point in a pair of rotated hexagonal lattices is closest to the origin?*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3829536/284619) and [How did Gaussian and Eisenstein integers get their names?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/12560/3869)