# Theory of irreducible elements in terms of principal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, soft-question

Let $R$ be an integral domain with $1$. Here are some standard definitions:

> Let $a \in R$ be a nonzero nonunit. $a$ is *irreducible* if $a = bc$ implies $b \in R^\times$ or $c \in R^\times$. $R$ is called a *factorization domain* if every nonzero nonunit of $R$ can be written as a product of irreducibles.

I noticed that this can be stated in terms of principal ideals:

> Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of principal ideals of $R$, excluding $(0)$ and $R$. $I \in \mathcal{P}$ is *irreducible* if $I$ is not the product of two ideals in $\mathcal{P}$. $R$ is called a *factorization domain* if every $I \in \mathcal{P}$ can be written as a product of irreducible ideals in $\mathcal{P}$.

I think this is somewhat cleaner to think about, and better motivates PID => UFD. My question is, are there any texts which treat the theory of irreducible elements in terms of ideals? And/or, what is your opinion on this presentation?

Comment: You may find of interest the surveys by Mott on divisibility groups cited in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66572/242).

Comment: Converting statements about divisibility of elements into corresponding statements about divisibility of principal ideals does not seem to be much of a simplification or motivation for PID => UFD.  But this is a subjective judgement.  There is certainly a need to introduce factorization of ideals when studies progress much beyond this point, i.e. into non-unique factorization domains.  See for example [Lack of unique factorization of ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39767/lack-of-unique-factorization-of-ideals).