# how to start a proof of a system of congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a$, $b$, $m$, and $n$ be integers with $m > 0$, $n >0$, and $gcd(m,n) = 1$. Then the system $x\equiv a$ (mod n) and $x\equiv b$ (mod m) has a unique solution modulo mn.

This is not the Chinese Remainder Theorem just yet. That is the next proof. This is a proof leading up to it.

Help please!

Comment: Try using $x = mq + b$ and using $mq + b \equiv a$ (mod n)

Comment: Do you want to show *existence* too, or only *uniqueness*. If both then it is already CRT.

Comment: For some people CRT is for a general system, and a $2\times 2$ system is the lemma that makes the proof simple.

Comment: This is just the uniqueness.

Comment: @vadim123 Right, the many variations on what CRT denotes are almost too many to count.

Comment: The previous theorem states, the system $x\equiv a$ (mod n) and $x \equiv b$ (mod m) has a solution if and only if $gcd(n,m) | a-b$. It may be useful to use?

Comment: @Franky That yields the *existence* of solutions. This exercise yields the *uniqueness*. Presumably the next exercise combines them into CRT. Do you already know that $\, m,n\mid k\,\Rightarrow\,{\rm lcm}(m,n)\mid k\, ?\ \ $

Comment: We know that $gcd(a,b) \times lcm(a,b) = ab$.

Comment: @Franky From that you have $\ m,n\mid k\,\Rightarrow\,mn\mid mk,nk\,\Rightarrow\,mn\mid \gcd(mk,nk)=\gcd(m,n)k\,$ therefore $\,{\rm lcm}(m,n) = mn/\gcd(m,n)\mid k.$ But there are [more direct,  conceptual ways](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/322153/242)

Comment: For more on lcm see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/3149/242) and [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/127344/242)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\,x',x\,$ are two solutions then $\,m,n\mid x'-x\,$ so $\ \ldots\mid x'-x$