# Greatest Common Divisor implies Least Common Multiple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

> If $a$ and $b$ are elements in an integral domain with unity 1$\neq$0. Show that $a$ and $b$ have a least common multiple if $a$ and $b$ have a highest common factor.

More generally there is a problem of showing that if any finite non-empty non-zero subset of the ring has a highest common factor, then any finite non-empty non-zero subset of the ring has a least common multiple.  (Actually the converse of the preceding sentence is also true.)

Comment: HINT: Think in the integers, if $a$ and $b$ were integers, then $gcd(a,b)lcm(a,b)=ab$. This should serve as an inspiration.

Comment: Yes that is fantastic.  I would love my candidate for $lcm(a,b)$ to be $hcf(a,b)a'b'$ where $hcf(a,b)a'=a$ and $hcf(a,b)b'=b$.  The problem is, when I consider $c$ to be another multiple, I want to show that $c$ actually is a multiple of $a$ and $b$ too.  This amounts to showing that $hcf(a,b)a'b' \mid c$, which is unclear how to do, since I can't even break things down into finitely many irreducibles (as the ring may not be Noetherian).

Comment: Note that your comment in the prior question has it the wrong way around.

Answer (score 3):

It's true that $\rm\,lcm(a,b)\:$ exists $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\:gcd(a,b)\:$ exists - see the Theorem below.  But the converse fails, e.g. as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2392588/242), in $\Bbb Q[x^2,x^3]$ we have $\,\gcd(x^2,x^3)=1\,$ but ${\rm lcm}(x^2,x^3)$ does not exist. Or, for simple well-known counterexamples in quadratic number fields see the paper linked below.

**Theorem**  $\rm\;\; (a,b) = ab/[a,b] \;\;$  if $\;\rm\ [a,b] \;$  exists.

**Proof**:  $\rm\quad\quad d\:|\:a,b \;\iff\; a,b\:|\:ab/d \;\iff\; [a,b]\:|\:ab/d \;\iff\; d\:|\:ab/[a,b] \quad\;\;$ **QED**

For further discussion see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88411/242) and  see also Khurana, [On GCD and LCM domains](https://pdf.zlibcdn.com/dtoken/07afa1e889e3b508fd5fda2d6995fa48/bf02837870.pdf), and for basic properties of gcd and lcm (in cancellative commutative monoids) see also Section 1.6, Factorization in Commutative Monoids,
in Robert Gilmer, *Commutative Semigroup Rings*, 1984.

Comment: @Bill Thanks for your help; I'm still unclear though.  Why are you allowed to "divide" $ab$ by $[a,b]$ or by $d$.  This is the issue I'm facing.

Comment: @user710587 $\rm\:d\:|\:b\:$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\:ad\:|\:ab,\:$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\:d\:|\:a(b/d).\:$ By definition of LCM, $\rm\:a,b\:|\:ab\:$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\:[a,b]\:|\:ab.\:$ And $\rm\:d\:|\:ab/[a,b]\:$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\:d[a,b]\:|\:ab\:$ $(\Rightarrow$ $\rm\:d\:|\:ab)\:$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\:[a,b]\:|\:ab/d,\:$ etc. These are inferences one can make mentally with a little practice, analogous to scaling and reducing fractions. See the linked post for the *universal* definitions of GCD and LCM and further discussion.