# How I prove the uniqueness of LCM of two non zero integers a, b?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that the least common multiple of two non zero integers is unique. Need to know how to prove the theorem. Thanks.

Comment: Any attempts to this you would like to share ?

Comment: And I need to know what you tried. And many other things ;-)

Answer (score 4):

There is a theorem which follows from induction called the Well Ordering Principle, which says that any non-empty set of positive integers has a least element. It is easy to show that a least element is unique.

Given two non-zero integers, $m,n$, the set of positive common multiples is non-empty since it contains $|mn|$.  So the least common multiple must exist and be unique.

Answer (score 2):

The proof depends on your definition of lcm. If it is defined as the least element of the set of positive common multiples then *uniqueness* is clear, since if $\rm\:m,n\:$ are both lcms then by the leastness of both $\rm\: m\le n,\, n\le m\:\Rightarrow\: n = m,\,$ since $\rm\,n\,$ is sandwiched between $\,\rm m\,$ and $\,\rm m.\,$ For *existence*, the set of common multiples of a nonempty *finite* set omitting $\,0\,$ is always nonempty, since the product of the elements of the set is a nonzero common multiple of each element (nonzero since a product of nonzero elements remains nonzero in any integral domain).

If, instead, you use the universal definition $\rm\: a,b\mid c\iff lcm(a,b)\mid c\:$ then the uniqueness follows similarly, i.e. if $\rm\,m,n\,$ are lcms of $\rm \,a,b\,$ then choosing $\rm\,c=m\,$ and $\rm\,c=n\,$ above yields that  $\rm\:m\mid n,\, n\mid m,\:$ so $\rm\:m = n\:$ if lcms are normalized to be positive. But in general domains we can only conclude the lcm is unique up to a unit (invertible) factor $\,\rm u,\,$  i.e. $\rm\,n = um,\,$ and there may be no effective algorithm to choose such [normalize unit multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3009888/242), such as choosing positives in $\Bbb Z$ or monics (lead coef $=1$) in $\,\Bbb Q[x] =\,$  polynomials in $x$ with rational coef's.

The universal definition is preferred since not only does it work in any domain, but it helps to greatly simply diverse proofs involving gcds and lcms (e.g. [here).](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88411/242) It is a prototyical example of a point that I [often emphasize:](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+dubuque+uniqueness+powerful++tools+equalities) uniqueness theorems provide powerful tools for proving equalities.